# Recursion doesn't happen any more or doesn't happen correctly if I store the recursive relationship in a variable first

Tags: recursion

I know the following code will form a recursion:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
u[i_, n_] := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]
u[0, n_] := n
u[i_, 0] := i

u[2, 2] 
(* => 8 *)
```

But if I store the recursive relationship in a variable first, the recursion will fail:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]
u[i_, n_] := exp
u[0, n_] = n
u[i_, 0] = i

u[2, 2] 
(* ERROR *)
```

Why? I guess maybe `exp` "shields" `i` and `n`, so, I tried something like:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]
u[i1_, n1_] := (i = i1; n = n1; exp)
u[0, n_] := n
u[i_, 0] := i
u[2, 2]
Table[Table[{i, u[i, n]}, {i, 0, 2}], {n, 0, 2}];
u[2, 2]
(* =>5
   =>5 *)
```

…As you see, it doesn't give the right answer.

A even "amazing" case is this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]
u[i1_, n1_] := (i = i1; n = n1; u[i, n] = exp)
u[0, n_] := n
u[i_, 0] := i
u[2, 2]
Table[Table[{i, u[i, n]}, {i, 0, 2}], {n, 0, 2}];
u[2, 2]
(* =>5 
   =>14 *)
```

Ah…the process of recursion is so complex, how to explain all these? And, how to solve the original problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first problem snippet:

```
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1];
u[i_, n_] := exp;
```

The way I think Mathematica does the evaluation of the body of `u` when you give the parameters 2 2, more or less, is like this:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1];

(* a more-or-less accurate model of function evaluation *)
Hold[exp] /. {i -> 2, n -> 2} // ReleaseHold

(* u[-1 + i, n] + u[i, -1 + n] *)
```

So what's happening is that there is no literal `i` or `n` symbol in the literal expression of the function. There is no `i` or `n` in `exp`. So by the time the `Hold` is released, the symbol replacement has already occurred and done nothing, and you end up with a recursive chain of no replacements. One way to force evaluation even within Hold is with `Evaluate`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1];
Hold[Evaluate[exp]] /. {i -> 2, n -> 2} // ReleaseHold

(* u[1, 2] + u[2, 1] *)
```

Translating this back into the function definition:

```
...
u[i_, n_] := Evaluate[exp];
...
```

Which works as expected.

---

In your second problem snippet:

```
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]
u[i1_, n1_] := (i = i1; n = n1; exp)
```

We use the same "model" as before:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1];
Hold[(i = i1; n = n1; exp)] /. {i1 -> 2, n1 -> 2} (* // ReleaseHold *)

(* Hold[i = 2; n = 2; exp] *)
```

Where you can see that you're assigning into the global symbols of `i` and `n`. Maybe that's your intention, and if you `ReleaseHold` this single application evaluates to the expected expression, but I imagine it would give weird answers because of the multiple branches (after the left branch reaches bottom, those bottom-most `i` and `n` are used at the top of the right branch, I think... or something like that. `brainhurt`).

Mr. Wizard's `Block[{i = i1, n = n1}, exp]` approach is one way to accomplish the goal here. Throwing it into our evaluation model:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1];
Hold[Block[{i = i1, n = n1}, exp]] /. {i1 -> 2, n1 -> 2} // ReleaseHold

(* u[1, 2] + u[2, 1] *)
```

Which evaluates to the correct value but also works in the general case because `Block` keeps the scope of those `i` and `n` within its subexpressions.

---

A general note: [Trace](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) can come in very handy in things like this. It will show you for example whether the `i` and `n` are being replaced or not.

Comment: I did try that `=` form but it didn't work, maybe because I wasn't clearing my variables or something. But anyways, it looks like there is a difference of some kind. If you try both versions, the `=` version gives a recursion error because it's not delayed. The code still runs though, so I'm not sure if it makes an actual difference in usage. The DownValues are exactly the same except for `=` and `:=`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've cleared all my variables and tried the solution with `Evaluate`, it works…

Comment: @xzczd you're right, these are not the same; I retract my earlier comment, and I am exploring this.

Comment: I tried to `Trace` my problematic codes but… `brainbreak`…Anyway, now I have two ways to avoid this problem, also thanks to @Mr.Wizard !

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish, so my apology if this doesn't answer your question in full

```
u[i_, n_] := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]
```

This line of code creates a `DownValue` for `u` that describes a function in the form of a replacement rule, transforming the left-hand-side of `:=` into the right-hand-side.  In use, expressions which match the named patterns `i_` and `n_` will be substituted into the RHS in place of `i` and `n`.  If `i` or `n` is not found *explicitly* on the RHS the expressions are simply discarded; they are *not* set as values to global symbols `i` and `n`.

Hopefully this description is enough for you to see that `u[i_, n_] := exp` cannot work.  You can manually assign values (temporarily) to global symbols using `Block` to force it to work:

```
u[ii_, nn_] := Block[{i = ii, n = nn}, exp]
```

This is usually a bad idea however: if somehow `n` or `i` have a value set outside of this construct (which conceivably could happen in a more complicated recursion) the results will be incorrect.  By comparison `SetDelayed` (`:=`) automatically scopes the variables that correspond to named patterns so this is prevented.

If you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish I may have a more helpful suggestion.

---

Based on your comment below you may find value in applying the transformation rules manually as follows.  `RuleDelayed` takes the place of `SetDelayed`, and it shares the latter's automatic scoping.

```
ClearAll[u]

recursion1 =  {u[i_, 0] :> i,
               u[0, n_] :> n, 
               u[i_, n_] :> u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]};

u[2, 2] //. recursion1
```

> 8

Be aware that the rules are tried in the explicit order given rather than the automatic ordering of DownValues.  This is why I placed the zero rules first.

Comment: …To tell you the truth, this question is generated in the process of figuring out the mistake of PlatoManiac's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-to-discretize-a-nonlinear-pde-fast). In his code, it's necessary to store the recursive relationship in a variable first, and, you're right, though the trick with `Block` works for my sample, it's not effective for the complicated original one.

Comment: @xzczd I'm not in the mood to work though a big lump of code but I added an example to my answer that may be helpful.

Comment: Er…seems that `RuleDelayed` is also unable to climb over the obstacle of intermediate variable. Something like `exp := u[i - 1, n] + u[i, n - 1]; recursion1 =  {u[i_, 0] :> i, u[0, n_] :> n, u[i_, n_] :> exp}; u[2, 2] //. recursion1` doesn't work.

Comment: @xzczd I didn't mean to imply it would; I'm just trying to offer another way to "store the recursive relationship."