# Expressions containing globally undefined symbols inside a function where they are defined

Tags: functions, programming, function-construction, scoping

Consider the following code.

```
f[a_,b_]:=x
x=a+b;
f[1,2]
(* a + b *)
```

From a certain viewpoint, one might expect it to return `3` instead of `a + b`: the symbols `a` and `b` are defined during the evaluation of `f` and `a+b` should evaluate to their sum.

Why is this viewpoint wrong? What's the right way to make it behave the way I want it to? (Something more clever than `f[p_,q_]:=x/.{a->p,b->q};`.)

Comment: This viewpoint *is* wrong. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808), and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia/20776#20776).

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: [(11461)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11461/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Analysis

In *Mathematica* when a definition is *applied* the expressions (arguments) that match pattern objects on the left-hand-side (LHS) are substituted into the matching right-hand-side (RHS) names before it is evaluated.  This is separate from the evaluation that does or does not take place at the time the rule or definition is created.  This substitution-before-evaluation is invariant between `Set` and `SetDelayed`.

Please consider this example:

```
ClearAll[f, a, b, x]

f[a_, b_] = (Print["one: ", a, b]; x);

x := Print["two: ", a, b];

f[1, 2]

{a, b} = {3, 4};

f[1, 2]
```

> one: ab
>
> two: ab
>
> two: 34

- The use of `Set` in the definition creation causes the RHS to evaluate, printing "one:", but this `Print` is not part of the definition created as it does not remain in the evaluated form of `(Print["one: ", a, b]; x)`.
- When the definition is used no `a` or `b` appear in the explicit unevaluated RHS (`x`) therefore no substutions are made.  The RHS is then evaluated and the `Print` statement in the global definition of `x` fires.
- Between the first and second time the function is used `a` and `b` are given global values.  When the function is next called the same evaluation sequence takes place but when `x` evaluates to `Print["two: ", a, b]` this time `a` and `b` evaluate to `3` and `4`.

---

### Alternatives

You asked for "something more clever than `f[p_,q_]:=x/.{a->p,b->q};`" but that may in essence be what you need.  This code effectively performs the substitution *after* the RHS evaluation each time the definition is applied.  If you want to use the argument values *during* evaluation you will need to use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) or another function that works like `Block`.  Here is an example:

```
ClearAll[f, a, b, x]
f[aa_, bb_] := Block[{a = aa, b = bb}, x]

x = a + b;
f[1, 2]

x = 3 a + b^2;
f[1, 2]
```

> ```
> 3
>
> 7
> ```

All that remains is to make construction of these definitions easier which we can do with a little meta-programming.  Here is one method:

```
SetAttributes[blockSet, HoldFirst]

blockSet[LHS_ := RHS_] :=
 With[{subs = 
    Cases[Unevaluated[LHS], 
     Verbatim[Pattern][p_, x_] :> Append[Hold[p], Module[{p}, p]], -2]},
  {
    ReplaceAll[Hold[LHS], HoldPattern[#] :> #2 & @@@ subs],
    Set @@@ Hold @@ subs
  } /. {Hold[newLHS_], Hold[sets__]} :> (newLHS := Block[{sets}, RHS])
 ]
```

Now:

```
Remove[f, a, b, x]

blockSet[
  f[a_, b_] := x
]

?f
```

> ```
> Global`f
>
> f[a$752_, b$753_] := Block[{a = a$752, b = b$753}, x]
> ```

And:

```
x = a + b;
f[1, 2]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Comment: One issue with this approach is that the user might like to use the definition of `x` at the time `blockSet` is evaluated, instead of at the time `f` is evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

I gave the following answer to essentially the same [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184624/45431):

```
TagSetDelayed[x, lhs_, rhs_] ^:= SetDelayed @@ (Hold[lhs, rhs] /. OwnValues[x])
```

For your example:

```
x = a + b;
x /: f[a_, b_] := x
```

Then:

```
f[1, 2]
```

> 3

The main difference between this answer and @Mr.Wizard's answer is the time at which `x` is evaluated. In my answer,  the [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues) of `x` at the time of function *definition* is used. In @Mr.Wizard's answer, the [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues) of `x` at the time of function *application* is used. Let's see an example where this difference manifests:

```
x = a + b;
x /: f[a_, b_] := x
```

The [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) of `f` are:

```
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[a_, b_]] :> a + b}

Notice that no trace of `x` remains. If I change `x` to something else, and then evaluate `f`:

```
x = 1;
f[1, 2]
```

> 3

The function `f` does not change when `x` is changed. Now, for @Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
x = a + b;
blockSet[f[a_, b_] := x]
```

Notice that the [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues) of `x` have not been used in the definition of `f`:

```
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[a$29662_, b$29663_]] :> Block[{a = a$29662, b = b$29663}, x]}

If I change `x`:

```
x = 1;
f[1, 2]

x = a-b;
f[1, 2]

x = 22;
f[1, 2]
```

> 1
>
> -1
>
> 22

Notice how the definition of `f` is dependent on the value of `x`. This difference in behavior should be considered when choosing which approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

check :

```
f[1,2]//Trace
```

You will see that 1 & 2 are passed first before replacing x with its value.

If you want to get your result then use `Set` not `SetDelayed`

```
Clear[a,b];
x=a+b;   
f[a_,b_]=x;
f[1,2]

(*3*)
```

Comment: Algohi your second example caught me off guard until I took a second look.  It may not work in the way that you think it does.  The use of `Set` does not cause the right-hand-side of the definition to be (re)evaluated before substitution *at the time the function is used.*  Rather it only causes RHS evaluation at the time the definition is constructed.  If you start with `Clear[x]` you will see that the result is `a + b` just as it was in the original example. (@Igor note this too.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard absolutely correct. correction is added.

Answer (score 1):

One somewhat organized way to get what you want is to be very explicit about which expressions are functions and which are values. For example, your x is really a function of a and b, but you are writing x=a+b. If instead, you make the functional relationships explicit, then there is less chance of confusion. In the simplest case:

```
x[a_, b_] := a + b;
f[a_, b_] := x[a, b];
f[1, 2]
```

Now it is clear why f[1,2] returns 3.