# nonatomic expression expected when trying to sum of the integrals of two functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

newbie to MMA.

After computing the following two integrals:

```
min1 = 0;
min2 = 0;
max1 = 1.00;
max2 = 1.00;
density = (1/(max1 - min1)) (1/(max2 - min2));


Integrate[(2 x1 - max1) density Boole[ 
    x1 + x2 >= s >= 0 && x1 >= p1 >= 0 && min1 <= x1 <= max1 && 
     min2 <= x2 <= max2], {x1, min1, max1}, {x2, min2, max2}];
b1 = Part[%, 1];
g1[s_] := Piecewise[b1, 0];


Integrate[(2 x2 - max2) density Boole[ 
    x1 + x2 >= s >= 0 && x2 >= p2 >= 0 && min1 <= x1 <= max1 && 
     min2 <= x2 <= max2], {x1, min1, max1}, {x2, min2, max2}];
b2 = Part[%, 1];
g2[s_] := Piecewise[b2, 0];
```

It returns `"Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Last[0]. "` when I try to add them up:

```
d1 = Simplify[g1[s_] + g2[s_]]
```

The sum works if I eliminate `x1 >= p1 >= 0` and `x2 >= p2 >= 0` respectively, but I cannot figure out why it does not work after including these two conditions.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (short form `:=`) to define the function `g1` or `g2` you prevent the evaluation of `b1` or `b2` respectively into the assigned expression, so e.g. `g1` has for its complete definition:

```
?? g1
```

> Global`g1
>
> ```
> g1[s_]:=Piecewise[b1,0]
> ```

Parameter substitutions into the right-hand-side are made before further evaluation, and since there is no literal `s` in the unevaluated form of `Piecewise[b1,0]` your function does not work correctly.

Using instead [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (short form `=`) the expressions `b1` and `b2` are expanded in the definition of `g1` and `g2`.

```
g1[s_] = Piecewise[b1, 0];
g2[s_] = Piecewise[b2, 0];

Simplify[g1[s] + g2[s]]   (* outputs large Piecewise expression and no errors *)
```

Recommended reading:

- [Expressions containing globally undefined symbols inside a function where they are defined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)