# Passing a function as an argument to another function using the same variables

Tags: functions

I define a function with two variables and an argumment which is a function of this two first variables.
For example the function Ttrho below (the two variables are T and Rho and pTt is a function of T or Rho or both):

```
getAllVariables[expr_] := 
Union@Cases[expr, 
Except[__Symbol?(Context@# === 
     "System`" &), _Symbol], {1, ∞}, Heads -> True];

Ttrho[T_, ρ_, pTt_] := 
With[{var = getAllVariables[pTt]}, Print[var]; 
If[Length@var > 0, 
Apply[pTt, var /. Thread[var -> {T, ρ}]] 5 0.069/ρ, 
pTt*5 0.069/ρ]]
```

I would like that the three results below must have the same value:

```
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[{T, ρ}, T]]
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[{ρ, T}, T]]
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[T, T]]
```

But I obtain actually the following results:

During evaluation of In[1]:= {T,ρ}

Out[1]= 3.45

During evaluation of In[2]:= {T,ρ}

Out[2]= 0.345

During evaluation of In[3]:= {T}

During evaluation of In[3]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {T}->{1,0.1} cannot be combined.

Out[3]= 3.45

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am struggling to understand the motivation behind this question and therefore the actual behavior that you are seeking.  However it seems to me that perhaps you want something like this.

```
ClearAll[Ttrho]

Ttrho[xT_, xρ_, HoldPattern@Function[_, body_]] := 
  Block[{T = xT, ρ = xρ}, body]

Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[{T, ρ}, 3 T]]
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[{ρ, T}, 3 T]]
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[T, 3 T]]
```

> ```
> 3
>
> 3
>
> 3
> ```

This will *only* work with actual `Function` expressions as shown, not generic functions of any kind, but since you appear to want commonality of parameter names I think this is implied.

#### Application

To make this "elegant" please load my `blockSet` function from [(69595)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69595/121) then:

```
ClearAll[Ttrho]

blockSet[
  Ttrho[T_, ρ_, pTt_] := pTt[[2]]*5 0.069/ρ
]

Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[{T, ρ}, T]]
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[{ρ, T}, T]]
Ttrho[1, 0.1, Function[T, T]]
```

> ```
> 3.45
>
> 3.45
>
> 3.45
> ```

This also relies on the third argument of `Ttrho` being an explicit `Function` as `pTt[[2]]` is used to extract its body.

Comment: The motivation is that Ttrho is a function which represents a property of fluids. This property has a general shape for all fluids but some coefficients like pTt are different functions (it can also be a constant) for different fluids. These functions (or constants) are given in a dataset. So T and rho represents always the same physical quantity. So when the parameter ptT is simply a constant (rather than a function) it is simpler for the user to put the value instead of writing a function?

Comment: Does with the blockset function, ptT can be any kind of function?

Comment: @F.Aitken I just read your comments, and pardon me, but I'm not sure I understand this any better.  The issue I see is that you have a function `Function[{T, ρ}, T]` and a function `Function[{ρ, T}, T]` which have the parameters in different order; the *only* way to tell which parameter is `T` and which is `ρ` is to "look" at those Symbols themselves.  If we had another function `Function[{x, y}, 2 x + y]` what should we (and our `Ttrho`) make of it?  Likewise `2 # + #2 &` or any other generic function that does not have *explicit* parameters `T` and/or `ρ`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Symbol` and the [Parts of Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html) tutorial.

With

```
tRho[t_, rho_, f_Function] :=
 (f[[2]] /. {Symbol["t"] -> t, Symbol["rho"] -> rho}) 5 0.069/rho
```

Then

```
tRho[1, 0.1, Function[{t, rho}, t]]
tRho[1, 0.1, Function[{rho, t}, t]]
tRho[1, 0.1, Function[t, t]]
```

> ```
> 3.45
> 3.45
> 3.45
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To complete this you still need to localize `t` and `rho`.  Presently these symbols evaluate as a result of both `f[[2]]` and `Symbol["t"]` etc.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm not certain I am following what you are saying. If I evaluate `t = 10*10^9` and then evaluate `tRho[1, 0.1, Function[t, t]]` then I still get `3.45`.  Why do I need to localise with `Module` or `Block`?

Comment: Your example works but for the wrong reason. :^)  You end up with something like `10000000000 /. 10000000000 -> new` but one should never let it get to that point.  Consider `t := RandomReal[]` instead; now the function is broken!  Our code should be robust against such things.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So true. Trace reveals all.  That would have been one nasty bug to locate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `Function[{T, ρ}, body]` expression `T` and `ρ` are just "dummy variables", their names are not really meaningful, only meaningful thing is relation between `T` and `ρ` symbols, used inside function `body`, to positions of those symbols in arguments list. [*Mathematica* can rename function variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html), to avoid conflicts in nested scopes. So even if `T` or `ρ` was typed inside `Function`, resulting expression can contain different symbols. That's why extraction of function body and identification of variables, that you asked for in question, can be tricky.

I would take advantage of *Mathematica* symbolic capabilities and, instead of `Function`s, I'd use expressions containing globally meaningful symbols. So I'd put `T` and `ρ` in some context, that I'd keep on `$ContextPath`, and, instead of `Function[{T, ρ}, T]`, just pass `T` to your `Ttrho` function.

I would also separate concerns of calculating `Ttrho` expression and of inserting numerical values for `T` and `ρ`.

Putting it together I'd use something like this:

```
BeginPackage@"myThermodynamics`"; Unprotect@"`*"; ClearAll@"`*"

T::usage = "T is something";
ρ::usage = "ρ is something else";
Ttrho::usage = "Ttrho[pTt] returns something";

Begin@"`Private`"; ClearAll@"`*"

someConstant = 5 0.069;

Ttrho@pTt_ := someConstant pTt/ρ

End[]; Protect@"`*"; EndPackage[];
```

So now you can calculate symbolic expression for `Ttrho` and insert numeric values like this:

```
Ttrho[T]
% /. {T -> 1, ρ -> 0.1}
(* (0.345 T)/ρ *)
(* 3.45 *)

Ttrho[ρ^3/T^2]
% /. {T -> 1, ρ -> 0.1}
(* (0.345 ρ^2)/T^2*)
(* 0.0345 *)
```

---

If you really need to extract body from already existing `Function` expression you could use something like following:

```
funcToExpr // ClearAll
funcToExpr@func:HoldPattern@Function[
    Except[Null, var_Symbol] | {vars___Symbol},
    Repeated[_, 2]
] :=
    func @@ Flatten@Replace[HoldComplete[vars, var],
        s_ :> With[{name = SymbolName@Unevaluated@s},
            RuleCondition[
                ToExpression[Context@Unevaluated@s <> StringDrop[name, -1],
                    InputForm, HoldComplete
                ],
                StringEndsQ[name, "$"]
            ]
        ],
        {1}
    ]
```

Which should work also for `Function`s with renamed variables:

```
Function[T, T]
% // funcToExpr
(* Function[T, T] *)
(* T *)

With[{x = 2}, Function[T, x T]]
% // funcToExpr
(* Function[T$, 2 T$] *)
(* 2 T *)

Function[{T, ρ}, T ρ]
% // funcToExpr
(* Function[{T, ρ}, T ρ] *)
(* T ρ *)

With[{x = 2}, Function[{T, ρ}, x T ρ]]
% // funcToExpr
(* Function[{T$, ρ$}, 2 T$ ρ$] *)
(* 2 T ρ *)
```

Putting all things together:

```
Ttrho@funcToExpr@#3 /. {T -> #1, ρ -> #2} & @@@ {
  {1, 0.1, Function[{T, ρ}, T]},
  {1, 0.1, Function[{ρ, T}, T]},
  {1, 0.1, Function[T, T]}
}
(* {3.45, 3.45, 3.45} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanck you very much for the different propositions.
By using the blockSet function of Mr Wizard with the two additional conditions:

```
ClearAll[Ttrho]

ConstanteQ[f_] := 
NumberQ[f] == 
True || (QuantityQ[f] == True && (Head@f[[1]] === Function) == 
  False);
QuantityFunctionQ[f_] := 
 QuantityQ[f] == True && Head@f[[1]] === Function;

blockSet[
Ttrho[T_, \[Rho]_, pTt_: 1] := 
With[{fpTt = 
 If[ConstanteQ[pTt], pTt, 
  If[QuantityFunctionQ[pTt], Quantity[Last@pTt[[1]], pTt[[2]]], 
   pTt[[2]]]]},
fpTt*5 0.069/\[Rho]]
]
```

I obtained a great flexibility on the way in which the user can enter the function (or the constant) ptT. For the different examples below:

```
Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, Function[{T, \[Rho]}, 2 T]]
Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, Function[{\[Rho], T}, 2 T]]
Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, Function[T, 2 T]]

Ttrho[2, 0.1, Quantity[Function[T, 2 T], "Kelvins"]]
Ttrho[2, 0.1, Quantity[Function[{T, \[Rho]}, 2 T], "Kelvins"]]
Ttrho[2, 0.1, Quantity[Function[{\[Rho], T}, 2 T], "Kelvins"]]
Ttrho[2, 0.1, Function[T, Quantity[2 T, "Kelvins"]]]
Ttrho[2, 0.1, Function[{T, \[Rho]}, 2 T]]

Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, Function[T, 2]]
Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, 2]
Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, Function[T, Quantity[2, "Kelvins"]]]
Ttrho[Quantity[2, "Kelvins"], 0.1, Quantity[2, "Kelvins"]]

Ttrho[2, 0.1, Quantity[Function[\[Rho], 2 \[Rho]^2], "g/cm^3"]]
Ttrho[2, 0.1, Quantity[Function[{\[Rho]}, 2 \[Rho]], "g/cm^3"]]
```

You get the following results:

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[13.8, "Kelvins"]

13.8

6.9

6.9

Quantity[6.9, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[6.9, "Kelvins"]

Quantity[0.069, ("Grams")/("Centimeters")^3]

Quantity[0.69, ("Grams")/("Centimeters")^3]

Sorry I have not yet looked at the solution proposed by jkuczm and perhaps it has a greater flexibility than above?

Comment: It would be better, if you combined this with your original question.