# Forcing variable substitution on delayed evaluation

Tags: function-construction, replacement

Problem, the following snippet doesn't substitute vars

```
normal := MultinormalDistribution[{t1, t2}, cov];
fit[t1_, t2_, x1_, x2_] := PDF[normal, {x1, x2}];
fit[0, 0, 0, 0] (* is not numeric *)
```

I vaguely recall there was some way to make this give numeric result, something like `PDF@@{Evaluate@normal,{x1,x2}]` , does anyone know the common pattern to use here?

Comment: You could do `normal[t1_, t2_] := ... ` in the first line and `normal[t1,t2]` in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cov := {{2, -1/3}, {-1/3, 2/3}};

normal := MultinormalDistribution[{t1, t2}, cov];

(fit[t1_, t2_, x1_, x2_] := PDF[#, {x1, x2}]) & @ normal

fit[0, 0, 0, 1] // N
```

> ```
> 0.0635204
> ```

If you prefer a more automated approach or you cannot have even `normal` evaluate at the time of defining `fit` try `blockSet` from [Expressions containing globally undefined symbols inside a function where they are defined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)

```
ClearAll[fit]

blockSet[
  fit[t1_, t2_, x1_, x2_] := PDF[normal, {x1, x2}]
]

fit[0, 0, 0, 1] // N
```

> ```
> 0.0635204
> ```

The definition that was created:

```
?fit
```

> ```
> fit[t1$535_, t2$536_, x1$537_, x2$538_] := 
>   Block[{t1 = t1$535, t2 = t2$536, x1 = x1$537, x2 = x2$538},
>     PDF[normal, {x1, x2}]]
> ```

In most cases I would favor [anderstood's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18767/anderstood) recommendation of explicit parameter passing however.