# Definition of a function using variables outside of the function

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I would like to define a function using variables outside of the function.

For example,

```
g = x + y;
f[x_, y_] := g;
f[1, 2]
```

then, I hope to get 3 as the answer.
In above case, I get

```
x + y
```

as the answer.

Comment: Just change SetDelayed := sign by equal =

Comment: Further reading: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(69590)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121) -- if you expect to redefine `g` and have it affect `f` you will need that.  If `g` is defined before `f` only then `Set` (shorthand `=`) is sufficient.  Would you please clarify your intent?