# Globally Defining a Variable that Depends on Arguments of Functions

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, hold

I have many **delayed-defined** functions of many variables, and all the functions share a term containing some of these variables. Thus, I would like to just call the term `x` and for each function to immediately read `x` as that term. What would be the easiest/best/cleanest way to do this?

As a very simplified example, the code

```
x = a1 + a2;
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := x + a3
f[b1, b2, b3]
```

gives the output

> ```
> a1 + a2 + b3
> ```

but the output I want is

> ```
> b1 + b2 + b3
> ```

Given my problem, the following concerns and conditions are understandable.

- I want to avoid defining `x` explicitly as a function (i.e. `x[...]`) because it depends on many variables, it would be called many times, and `x[...]` would end up being almost as large as the term it is supposed to be a shortcut for.
- I want to avoid calling `Module[]` or `Block[]` or using replacement rules in each function because I would have to do this for many functions and they are complicated enough as it is. This is why I would like the definition for `x` to be global.

It seems like there should be a straightforward way for Mathematica to just immediately read a symbol `x` in each **delayed-defined** function as a term containing some of the functions' arguments.

Comment: Can you just use `f[a1_, a2_, a3_] = x + a3`?

Comment: I am using delayed-defined functions.

Comment: Would something like `globalEnvironment[x->a1+a2, f[a1_,a2_, a3_] = x+a3, g[a1_, a2_, a3_] = x^2-a3, ...]` work, or do you want to modify how `SetDelayed` works (i.e., modify a built-in symbol) so that you can just use `f[a1_,a2_, a3_] = x+a3; g[a1_, a2_, a3_] = x^2-a3`?

Comment: @Carl I would like something like the effects of `globalEnvironment`, except I wouldn't want to define a large number of big functions inside one function. I don't need to modify `SetDelayed` overall, except maybe for how it works  just the symbol `x`.

Comment: Despite your aversion to `Block` I believe it is the correct solution here.  I consider this question a duplicate of [(69590)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121), which I answered with `blockSet`; please try that before rejecting the idea.

Answer (score 4):

This does not avoid defining `x` as a function, but I believe it meets the required usage nonetheless, and involves no shenanigans with scoping constructs or replacement rules

```
xpattern = PatternSequence[a1_, a2_];
xfunc[xpattern] = a1 + a2;
f[x : xpattern, a3_] := xfunc[x] + a3
```

Now we have

```
f[b1, b2, b3]
(* b1 + b2 + b3 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about modifying `$Pre`?:

```
$Pre = Function[expr, 
   Unevaluated[expr] /. a__SetDelayed :> (Unevaluated@a /. OwnValues@x), HoldAll];

x = a1 + a2;
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := x + a3;
g[a1_, a2_, a3_] := x a3
DownValues /@ {f, g}

(* {{HoldPattern[f[a1_, a2_, a3_]] :> (a1 + a2) + a3}, 
    {HoldPattern[g[a1_, a2_, a3_]] :> (a1 + a2) a3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea. Create an [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for `x` so that using [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed) with the tag `x` does what you want:

```
TagSetDelayed[x, lhs_, rhs_]  ^:= SetDelayed @@ (Hold[lhs, rhs] /. OwnValues[x])
```

For your example:

```
x = a1 + a2;
x /: f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := x + a3
```

Check:

```
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[a1_, a2_, a3_]] :> (a1 + a2) + a3}

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You need to use `x /: f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := 1/x + a3`, that's the whole point of the TagSetDelayed definition.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What does ?x return?

Comment: Well nuts, it's working now (in a new session, two hours later) so I guess I had a lingering definition messing things up.  Noob mistake!  **Sorry,** and belated +1.  ( And to answer your question I get `x=a1+a2
 
(x/:lhs_:=rhs_)^:=SetDelayed@@(Hold[lhs,rhs]/. OwnValues[x])` )