# Calling a function on a variable with parameters

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I have an equation that contains parameters. I want to use it in a function like `NDSolve`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so. Here's an example:

I define my equation like so:

```
L := T - V
T := 1/2 m z'[t]^2
V := m g z[t]
eqn := Dt[D[L, z'[t]], t] - D[L, z[t]] == 0
```

Then, I want to use it in `NDSolve`, so I write the following:

```
solution[m_, g_] := NDSolve[{Evaluate[eqn], z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, z[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

This doesn't work as expected, though, and `solution[1, 1]` fails to output a result.

I also note that

```
theEqn[m_, g_] := Evaluate[eqn]
theEqn[1, 1]
```

works fine, and outputs

```
1 + z''[t] == 0
```

Furthermore, the following code (where I have just copied and pasted the definitions into the code) *does* work:

```
solution[m_, g_] := 
 NDSolve[{Dt[D[1/2 m z'[t]^2 - m g z[t], z'[t]], t] - 
     D[1/2 m z'[t]^2 - m g z[t], z[t]] == 0, z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, 
  z[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I feel there ought to be some way that I'm missing to do that substitution automatically. How do I do this?

Comment: (I can also get it working by making `L`, `T`, `V`, and `eqn` explicit functions of `m` and `g`, but this looks awful, isn't easily modified, and seems overly complicated.)

Comment: Proposed duplicates: [(11461)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11461/121), [(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121).  Also related: [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121)

Comment: `Evaluate` only works when applied to items at level 1 in an argument sequence. Your `eqn` appears at level 2.

Comment: Ah, cool. How can I fix that, then?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Interesting, I haven't been able to find anything about the scoping so far. I'll take a look at those.

Comment: @Matthew Please try my `blockSet` abstraction from [(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121) and tell me if your function behaves as desired; I believe it will.

Comment: I looked at that page and I think I have an answer to this that's fairly unintrusive.

Comment: The following works. `With[{eqn = eqn /. {m -> 1, g -> 1}}, NDSolve[{eqn, z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, z[t], {t, 0, 10}]]`. Perhaps you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that made this work in the end was using dummy variables as the function parameters. This then allowed me to use `/.` to replace variables.

```
solution[mm_, gg_] := 
 NDSolve[{eqn /. {m -> mm, g -> gg}, z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, 
  z[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I think this is a pretty unintrusive solution, since it only affects one line of code and I can write the rest as usual.

Comment: Did you try `blockSet`?  It does something much like this but in a more generalized way.

Comment: No, I didn't, but I'll try it for a future problem - I can see why it's useful, but the way I've got my problem set up, I think this works better.