# Defining function

Tags: function-construction

```
ver1 = 2 x
verf[x_] := ver1
verf[3]
```

Result : `2 x`

Expected Result : `6`

In the above code sample, `ver1` can change to expressions (`4 x + 3`,`3 x` etc)

What is wrong in the code? How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: Please also see: [(11461)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11461/121)

Comment: I missed 'Evaluate' in my code .. as suggested by @Enrique Pérez Herrero

Comment: If that is a solution for you simply use `=` (`Set`) rather than `:=` (`SetDelayed`) and leave out `Evaluate`, for the same effect.  I believed that you were looking for a somewhat different evaluation behavior as described in the marked duplicate; even if you are not you may wish to familiarize yourself with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use set delayed in `ver1`,  this is `ver1[x_]:= 2 x`,  you need to evaluate `ver1` when `verf` is defined:

```
ver1 = 2 x
verf[x_] := Evaluate[ver1]
verf[3]
```