# Can I generate a "piecewise" list from a list in a fast and elegant way?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, difference-equations, finite-difference-method

Suppose we have a number list `a`:

```
n = 1000000;
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n}];
```

We want to generate a list `c` with the same dimension of `a` and the relationship between the elements of `a` and `c` is:

> $c[[i]] == 2 a[[i]] +3$

I think there will be no doubt that the best way to get this `c` is:

```
c = 2 a + 3
```

However, what if `c` is a "piecewise" list i.e. elements in different part of `c` are generated by different formula? For example, `n/2` of the elements right in the middle of `c` are `0.` while others still follow the formula above.

The most direct way I can think out is:

```
c1 = Table[If[n/4 + 1 <= i <= 3 n/4, 0., 2 a[[i]] + 3 ], {i, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.7380000, Null}

It's simple, but too slow.

While these 2 approaches are fast:

```
(c2 = 2 a + 3 ; 
  c2[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4]] = ConstantArray[0., {n/2}];) // AbsoluteTiming
(c3 = ConstantArray[0., {n}];
  c3[[1 ;; n/4]] = 2 a[[1 ;; n/4]] + 3 ; 
  c3[[3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] = 2 a[[3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] + 3;) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0760000, Null}
>
> {0.0580000, Null}

But they are so dirty… And things will be worse when the dimension of the list becomes higher:

```
n=100;
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n}]

d1 = Table[
    If[n/4 + 1 <= i <= 3 n/4 && n/4 + 1 <= j <= 3 n/4 && 
      n/4 + 1 <= k <= 3 n/4, 0., 2 b[[i, j, k]] + 3 ], {i, n}, {j, 
     n}, {k, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(d3 = ConstantArray[0., {n, n, n}]; 
   d3[[1 ;; n/4]] = 2 b[[1 ;; n/4]] + 3; 
   d3[[3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] = 2 b[[3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] + 3;
   d3[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 1 ;; n/4]] = 
    2 b[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 1 ;; n/4]] + 3; 
   d3[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] = 
    2 b[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] + 3;
   d3[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 1 ;; n/4]] = 
    2 b[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 1 ;; n/4]] + 3; 
   d3[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] = 
    2 b[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4, 3 n/4 + 1 ;; -1]] + 3;); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {12.8440000, Null}
>
> {0.0930000, Null}

And a nightmare when the region are irregular:

```
f1 = Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 <= n^2, 0., 2 b[[i, j, k]] + 3 ], 
           {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.4530000, Null}

A fast `f3` with the method shown in `c3` and `d3` is of course possible, but I'd like to skip it now.

So my question is, as the title said, is there an approach that's both elegant as `c1` and fast as `c3`? Or at least not that slow as `c1` and not that dirty as `c3`? Or, I can't have my cake and eat it too?

---

Well, to be honest, I knew that `Compile` together with `Module` can somewhat help (thanks for the help of [@chyaong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyaong)!):

```
c11 = Compile[{}, Module[{a = a, n = n}, 
      Table[If[n/4 + 1 <= i <= 3 n/4, 0., 2 a[[i]] + 3], {i, n}]]][]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.3590000, Null}

But I still look forward to a better solution: maybe a little greed?

---

I'd like to point out that, though I chose "$f(a)$ and $0$" to generate list in the example above for the sake of simplicity, this question is more general, the generated list may be formed by "$f(a)$ and $g(a)$", or even by "$f(a1,a2)$ and $g(a1,a2)$". Still, I appreciated and will appreciate those answers that focus on special cases since the "$f(a)$ and $0$" cases are simple but also common.

I added the tag "difference-equations" because this question generated when exploring finite difference method (FDM). I believe it's a inevitable issue when programming FDM.

Here are two existed post that can be optimized or answered with the outcome of this discussion:

[How to discretize a nonlinear PDE fast?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-to-discretize-a-nonlinear-pde-fast/28011#28011)

[How do I solve a PDE with a strange boundary condition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18921/how-do-i-solve-a-pde-with-a-strange-boundary-condition)

Comment: Is there always be `0` or `f(a)` or it is more general question?

Comment: @Kuba Well, I should say it's more general… maybe the new list is generated by $f(a)$ and $g(a)$, or even $f(a1, a2)$ and $g(a1, a2)$…

Comment: If you have a `C` compiler installed you can get better speed up by calling that compiler. See my updated answer.

Comment: `c2[[n/4 + 1 ;; 3 n/4]] = 0.` is OK, no need `ConstantArray[0., {n/2}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now let me make use of the experience got from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61597/1871).

With the help of `CompilationTarget -> "C"` and `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` (both are indispensable), the `Table` approach turns out to be the most elegant and fast and universal. The 1D case:

```
n = 10^6;
a = RandomReal[1, n];

pxz = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {a, _Real, 1}}, 
   Table[If[n/4 + 1 <= i <= 3 n/4, 0., 2 a[[i]] + 3], {i, n}], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

pxz[n, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0430000, Null}
> ```

Timings of other solutions in my machine:

```
(* RunnyKine's solution *)
pp[n, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* chyaong's two solutions *)
r1 = (2 a + 3) BitXor[k, 1] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = (2 a + 3) k2 // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0970000, Null}
> {0.0890000, 65118127}
> {0.0850000, 65118127}
> ```

The `` Compile`GetElement `` trick doesn't show its power in this simple 1D case, but when it comes to the 3D irregular region:

```
o = 2 10^2;
b = RandomReal[1, {o, o, o}];

(* ybeltukov's approach, notice the tiny change *)
(2 b + 3)(1 - UnitStep[Outer[Plus,Range@o^2, Range@o^2, Range@o^2]- o^2]); // AbsoluteTiming

pxz3d1 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {a, _Real, 3}}, 
                 Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 > n^2, 0., 2 a[[i, j, k]] + 3], 
                       {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}], 
                 CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

pxz3d2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {a, _Real, 3}}, 
                 Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 > n^2, 0., 2 Compile`GetElement[a, i, j, k] + 3], 
                       {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}], 
                 CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

AbsoluteTiming[pxz3d1[o, b];]
AbsoluteTiming[data = pxz3d2[o, b];]
```

> ```
> {1.314000, Null}
> {0.3870000, Null}
> {0.2650000, Null}
> ```

```
Image3D[data]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:  chyaong says this doesn't auto-compile within `Array` in *Mathematica 9* and is therefore much slower.  My timings were performed in version 7.

---

This isn't going to be as fast as methods that compile to C, but using `Function` and `Array` provides a nice improvement and is very direct:

```
n = 100;
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n}];

r1 =
 Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 <= n^2, 0., 2 b[[i, j, k]] + 3], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}];//
  AbsoluteTiming

r2 =
 Array[{i, j, k} \[Function] If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 <= n^2, 0., 2 b[[i, j, k]] + 3], {n, n, n}];//
  AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {1.8391052, Null}
>
> {0.2390137, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Comment: `r2` is faster on v7, but on v9 about 15 times slower.

Comment: @chyaong That's surprising and disappointing!  :-O  Could you try setting `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"ArrayCompileLength" -> 5}]` and timing it again?  I can't understand why this would be de-optimized in v9.

Comment: I just tried that，but the elapsed time almost the same, I also think it's very strange.

Comment: `cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {b, _Real, 3}}, 
   Array[{i, j, k} \[Function] 
     If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 <= n^2, 0., 2 b[[i, j, k]] + 3], {n, n, n}]];
r2 = cf[n, b]; // AbsoluteTiming` ,On v9, I found this would be two times faster than v7.

Comment: @chyaong Thanks.  One shouldn't have to manually compile -- this is a regression that makes no sense to me.  Since I'm (*still!*) not using v9 it doesn't seem appropriate for me to ask it, but I'd like to open a Question on this subject.  Would you mind posting a question asking why this code doesn't auto-compile in v9?

Comment: This de-optimization has already existed since v8.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 2 10^6;
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n}];
k = UnitStep[# - n/4 - 1]~BitAnd~UnitStep[3 n/4 - #] &@Range[n];

k2 = With[{n = n}, Compile[x, n/4 + 1 <= x <= 3 n/4 // Not // Boole,
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]]@Range[n];

r1 = (2 a + 3) BitXor[k, 1] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = (2 a + 3) k2 // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.232013, 1123183045}
>
> {0.189011, 1123183045}

```
n = 100;
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n}];

With[{n = n, b = b},
    Compile[{}, 
     Table[If[i^2 + j^2 + k^2 <= n^2, 0., 2 b[[i, j, k]] + 3], 
       {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]]][] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming

(k2 = With[{n = n}, 
    Table[UnitStep[n^2 - (i^2 + j^2 + k^2)], {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]];
  (2 b + 3) BitXor[k2, 1] // Hash
  ) // AbsoluteTiming

(k3 = With[{n = n, k = Range@n}, 
    Table[UnitStep[n^2 - (i^2 + j^2 + k^2)], {i, n}, {j, n}]];
  (2 b + 3) BitXor[k3, 1] // Hash
  ) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.359021, 985443966}
>
> {0.294017, 985443966}
>
> {0.169010, 985443966}

Comment: Also faster than my `c11`, but maybe a little hard to extend to more general cases?

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 10^6;
a = RandomReal[1, n];   

First @ AbsoluteTiming @ MapIndexed[If[n/4 + 1 <= #2[[1]] <= 3 n/4, 0, #1] &, 2 a + 3];
```

> 3.390631

Well, we can speed this up dramatically by compiling to `C`:

```
pp = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {a, _Real, 1}}, MapIndexed[If[n/4 + 1 <= #2[[1]] <= 3 n/4, 0., #1] &,
            2 a + 3], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Then:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming @ pp[n, a];
```

> 0.031226

Comment: I'm sorry but this approach is even slower than my `c1` and no simpler than it.

Comment: @xzczd. How about now?

Comment: About 3 times faster than my `c11` now :).

Answer (score 2):

For the irregular region you can use

```
n = 100;
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n}];

(2 b + 3) UnitStep[Outer[Plus, Range@n^2, Range@n^2, Range@n^2] - n^2] // 
  Hash // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.084204, 6870340127317983824}

For comparison, chyaong's `k3` returns

> {0.101144, 6870340127317983824}