# Has this implementation of FDM touched the speed limit of Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, compile, difference-equations, finite-difference-method

Still, I'll use the implementation of the 1D FDTD method (you can simply understand it as a kind of explicit finite difference scheme for the [Maxwell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations)) as the example. Just for completeness, here is the 1D Maxwell's equation:

$$\mu  \frac{\partial H_y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial x}$$
$$\epsilon  \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial H_y}{\partial x}$$

and the corresponding finite difference equation:

$$H_y^{q+\frac{1}{2}}\left[m+\frac{1}{2}\right]\text{==}H_y^{q-\frac{1}{2}}\left[m+\frac{1}{2}\right]+\frac{\Delta _t}{\mu  \Delta _x}\left(E_z^q[m+1]-E_z^q[m]\right)$$
$$E_z^{q+1}[m]==E_z^q[m]+\frac{\Delta _t}{\epsilon  \Delta _x}\left(H_y^{q+\frac{1}{2}}\left[m+\frac{1}{2}\right]-H_y^{q+\frac{1}{2}}\left[m-\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)$$

The toy code <strike>I've repeatedly used in several posts</strike> implementing the difference scheme is:

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

fdtd1d = Compile[{{steps}}, 
   Module[{ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[ez[[2 ;; ie]] += (hy[[2 ;; ie]] - hy[[1 ;; ie - 1]]);
     ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10];
     hy[[1 ;; ie]] += (ez[[2 ;; ie + 1]] - ez[[1 ;; ie]]), {n, 
      steps}]; ez]];

result = fdtd1d[10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

*Notice that constants like $\mu$, $\Delta _t$ are omitted for simplicity.*

Personally I think it's a typical example for the implementation of [finite difference method (FDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method), so here's the question: has this piece of code (at least almost) touched the speed limit of *Mathematica*? In fact several months ago, I found that if the code is rewrited with *Julia*, it'll be [4 times faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23196530/1551513).

Indeed, I know this might be the case that one should use the best-suited tool for a specific job, but since I've already gained some stupid pride on using *Mathematica* and am unwilling to spend time to learn a new programming language (*Wolfram* is almost my first programming language, I used to learn some *VB*, but already gave it back to my teacher when started to use *Mathematica*), I still want to make sure if the *Mathematica* version of the code can be faster.

If it's the limitation, I'd like to know why there's such a big difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using `CompilePrint[fdtd1d]` we find that the first three instructions in the compiled function are calls to `MainEvaluate`. If you add `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` and repeat, the first two instructions are now `CopyTensor`, although there is virtually no difference in the timings between the two functions. This may mean nothing, or it may be something worth investigating.

Comment: Probably on reflection means little - the performance hit is likely later on.

Comment: Also there might be a further speed gain by compiling to C.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sadly the magic of C is ineffective here, at least with _TDM-GCC 4.8.1_ and _Vista 32bit_.

Comment: @blochwave Yeah, in this case `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` or changing the beginning part to `With[{ie2 = ie, ez2 = ez, hy2 = hy}, Compile[{{steps}}, Module[{ie = ie2, ez = ez2, hy = hy2}, …` or `With[{ie = 200}, Compile[{{steps}},  Module[{ez = Table[0., {ie + 1}], hy = Table[0., {ie}]}, …` doesn't help, the bottleneck is inside `Do`.

Comment: I also don't find a gain from compiling to C. However, since `Span` doesn't actually seem to feature in [this list of compilable functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), could that be a potential bottleneck?

Comment: As in, could rewriting it without the spans work...just wondering that's all

Comment: @blochwave That list isn't all… `Span` is compiled as we see with `CompilePrint`, and vectorization is still one of the most important way to speed up code even inside `Compile`,  rewriting `Span` with loops only makes the code slower. Try `fdtd1d = Compile[{{steps}}, Module[{ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy}, Do[Do[ez[[i + 1]] += (hy[[i + 1]] - hy[[i]]), {i, ie - 1}]; ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10]; Do[hy[[i]] += (ez[[i + 1]] - ez[[i]]), {i, ie}], {n, steps}]; ez]];`

Comment: Fair enough, didn't think it would be a solution, just curious!

Comment: Parallelization? GPUs?

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick AFAIK, compilation is hard to combine with  these techniques, which are much slower than compilation when used separately.

Comment: Not quite. CUDA (GPU) is really a compiled C code with CUDA instructions. If you add parallelization flag to your Compile[] command, you will get more speed-up for free. You probably can further add openmp instructions in your pre-compiled code, but I am not sure.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick Just scaned [this document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and tried several flags in `"CompileOptions"` (`-O3`, `-Ofast`, etc.) but didn't get a speed-up… Could you give an example? (BTW `-Ofast` does help in speeding up [this code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51250/1871) :D)

Comment: I meant simply adding Compile[<Your code>, Parallelization -> True]. Should generally be a quick-help type of a command.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick I'm sorry but this won't work, as the document said, `Parallelization -> True` only works together with `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`, it just makes a `Listable` compiled function paralleled, while it's not the case of this question.

Comment: Will it compile if you use ParallelDo instead of Do? And keeping Parallelisation->True. I was pretty sure it was parallelising not the argument calls, but the inner loops. Will check.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick No, it won't. `ParallelDo` isn't in the [list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/1871), the result of `CompilePrint` also shows it's indeed not compiled.

Comment: Nice question! I somehow missed it! (+1)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Okay, this is a bit of an embarassment.

Here is a very small modification of the original code. I simply made explicit option settings, made a denominator to `Sin` explicitly real, that kind of thing. My tests show the same timing as the original, give or take an iota.

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

fdtd1d = Compile[{{steps}}, 
   Module[{ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[ez[[2 ;; ie]] += (hy[[2 ;; ie]] - hy[[1 ;; ie - 1]]);
     ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.];
     hy[[1 ;; ie]] += (ez[[2 ;; ie + 1]] - ez[[1 ;; ie]]), {n, 
      steps}]; ez], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   "CompilationTarget" -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"];
```

I'll beef up the example a factor of 10.

```
result = fdtd1d[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out[172]= {0.555320, Null} *)
```

Now we remove the spans and replace with inner loops. No vectorization, that is.

```
fdtd1d2 = Compile[{{steps}}, Module[{ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy},
    Do[
     Do[ez[[j]] += (hy[[j]] - hy[[j - 1]]), {j, 2, ie}];
     Do[ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.];
      hy[[j - 1]] += (ez[[j]] - ez[[j - 1]]), {j, 2, ie + 1}], {n, 
      steps}]; ez], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   "CompilationTarget" -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"];

result2 = fdtd1d2[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
result2 == result

(* Out[174]= {0.179435, Null}

Out[175]= True *)
```

So that's a factor of 3. I guess I need to report this as a suggestion to revisit vector operations in `Compile`.

--- edit ---

It is of course slightly faster to take the assignment of `ez[[1]] =...` out of the second inner loop (sound of hand smacking forehead). Also it turns out to be slightly faster to reduce the index arithmetic in the second loop. I also took the assignment of the constant, `ie`, out of the `Module` variables and made it really constant using `With`; this does not seem to affect timing one way or the other.

```
fdtd1d3 = With[{ie = ie}, Compile[{{steps, _Integer}},
    Module[
     {ez = ez, hy = hy},
     Do[
      ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.];
      Do[ez[[j]] += (hy[[j]] - hy[[j - 1]]), {j, 2, ie}];
      Do[
       hy[[j]] += (ez[[j + 1]] - ez[[j]]), {j, 1, ie}],
      {n, steps}]; ez],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
    "CompilationTarget" -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]];

result3 = fdtd1d3[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
result3 === result2

(* Out[107]= {0.135636, Null}

Out[108]= True *)
```

So that's a modest improvement.

--- end edit ---

--- edit #2 ---

Per suggestion by @s0rce, we'll use `` Compile`GetElement `` instead of `Part`.

```
fdtd1d4 = Compile[{{steps, _Integer}},
   Module[
    {ie = ie, ez = ez, hy = hy},
    Do[
     ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.];
     Do[ez[[j]] += (Compile`GetElement[hy, j] - 
         Compile`GetElement[hy, j - 1]), {j, 2, ie}];
     Do[
      hy[[j]] += (Compile`GetElement[ez, j + 1] - 
         Compile`GetElement[ez, j]), {j, 1, ie}],
     {n, steps}]; ez],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   "CompilationTarget" -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"];

result4 = fdtd1d4[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
result4 === result2

(* Out[122]= {0.076532, Null}

Out[123]= True *)
```

Now that's progress.

--- end edit #2 ---

Comment: Just a side note, it's not necessary to make numbers inside `Sin` explicitly real and use `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`, and in some computer (for example mine) one may need to use something like `And @@ PossibleZeroQ[result2 - result // Chop]` to test the result. Then, this answer is really… surprising, it seems to be the first example in this site showing devectorizing can speed up code inside `Compile`.

Comment: `PossibleZeroQ` however will result in a call to the main evaluator. Best to do a numeric test with some granularity such as `result1==result2 || (Abs[result1-result2]/(Abs[result1]+Abs[result2])<epsilon` for suitable epsilon. (The first check should preclude the second one giving a division by zero issue.)

Comment: Does ``Compile`GetElement`` provide any speed up over `Part`?

Comment: @sOrce Yes, a huge one. Thanks. I'll reedit.

Comment: There's an additional 1.5X speedup by replacing e.g. ``ez[[j]] += (Compile`GetElement[hy, j] - Compile`GetElement[hy, j - 1]), {j, 2, ie}]`` with ``ez[[j]] = Compile`GetElement[ez, j] + (Compile`GetElement[hy, j] - Compile`GetElement[hy, j - 1]), {j, 2, ie}]`` etc.

Comment: Compared to OP's original method that's an overall 7.25X speed-up on my machine. Impressive!

Comment: @RunnyKine The `+=` variant is faster on my machine (running on Ubuntu Linux, with I know not what C compiler). I don't see why it is faster since `Compile`GetElement` seems to beat `Part` rather handily. But there it is. Platform weirdness at work.

Comment: But it should be faster since we're replacing `Part` on the RHS with ``Compile`GetElement`` and as you said ``Compile`GetElement`` beats `Part`, on that we agree. I'm on Windows with Visual Studio Compiler.

Comment: @RunnyKine With _TDM-GCC 4.8.1_, _Vista 32bit_, `ez[[j]] = Compile\`GetElement[ez, j]……` even makes the code a bit slower. The `Compile\`GetElement` trick is really amazing, now the code only takes about 13s for `steps = 10^7` in my computer, as fast as  the _Julia_ version (with the [`@inbounds` macro added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290917/can-i-take-advantage-of-parallelization-to-make-this-piece-of-code-faster?lq=1#comment35986126_23453661)). And if I set `"CompileOptions"->"-Ofast"` when loading the compiler, the timing will reduce to about 12.3s!

Comment: @xzczd It looks like Visual Studio is doing something interesting under the hood then.

Comment: @RunnyKine More likely to be a defect of TDM-GCC, I think.  Today I learned the basic syntax of C++ for several hours and rewrited the piece of code with it in order to find out if _12s_ touches the limit of my hardware. The result is, with optimization flag `-O3` or `-Ofast`, the C++ version only costs about _8s_ in my computer: that's a _1.5X_ speedup just as you got. So the compiler failed to dig out all the potential of the code.

Comment: @xzczd Good to know. In any case, this is an impressive speed up.

Comment: Hmm.. Don't know why the timing is different on my laptop: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ekm34.png .

Comment: Hi, @DanielLichtblau. As you said in the answer " I need to report this as a suggestion to revisit vector operations in Compile."  It's been 2 years, in the latest M11, the timing is the same... Is it technically so hard to make vector operation faster, considering MMA has such a powerful symbolic power( things like Symbolic C already there)? After all, they are absolutely equivalent, why will equivalent thing lead to different timing...