# Dramatic speed difference of code on MATLAB and Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, matlab

Background: I was trying to convert a MATLAB code (fluid simulation, SPH method) into a *Mathematica* one, but the speed difference is huge.

MATLAB code:

```matlab
function s = initializeDensity2(s)
nTotal   = s.params.nTotal;  %# particles
h    = s.params.h;
h2Sq = (2*h)^2;
for ind1 = 1:nTotal  %loop over all receiving particles; one at a time
%particle i is the receiving particle; the host particle
%particle j is the sending particle
xi = s.particles.pos(ind1,1);
yi = s.particles.pos(ind1,2);
xj = s.particles.pos(:,1); %all others
yj = s.particles.pos(:,2); %all others
mj = s.particles.mass; %all others
rSq = (xi-xj).^2+(yi-yj).^2;
%Boolean mask returns values where r^2 < (2h)^2
mask1 = rSq<h2Sq;
rSq   = rSq(mask1);
mTemp = mj(mask1);
densityTemp = mTemp.*liuQuartic(sqrt(rSq),h);
s.particles.density(ind1) = sum(densityTemp);
end
```

And the corresponding *Mathematica* code:

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
computeDistance[pos_] := 
DistanceMatrix[pos, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
initializeDensity[distance_] := 
uniMass*Total/@(liuQuartic[#,h]&/@Pick[distance,Boole[Map[#<2h&,distance,{2}]],1])
initializeDensity[computeDistance[totalPos]]
```

The data are coordinates of 1119 points, in the form of `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}...}`, stored in `s.particles.pos` and `totalPos` respectively. And `liuQuartic` is just a polynomial function. The complete MATLAB code is way more than this, but it can run about 160 complete time steps in 60 seconds, whereas the *Mathematica* code listed above alone takes about 3 seconds to run. I don't know why there is such huge speed difference. Any thoughts is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

The `liuQuartic` is defined as

```
liuQuartic[r_,h_]:=15/(7Pi*h^2) (2/3-(9r^2)/(8h^2)+(19r^3)/(24h^3)-(5r^4)/(32h^4))
```

and example data can be obtained by

```
h=2*10^-3;conWidth=0.4;conHeight=0.16;totalStep=6000;uniDensity=1000;uniMass=1000*Pi*h^2;refDensity=1400;gamma=7;vf=0.07;eta=0.01;cs=vf/eta;B=refDensity*cs^2/gamma;gravity=-9.8;mu=0.02;beta=0.15;dt=0.00005;epsilon=0.5;

iniFreePts=Block[{},Table[{-conWidth/3+i,1.95h+j},{i,10h,conWidth/3-2h,1.5h},{j,0,0.05,1.5h}]//Flatten[#,1]&];
leftWallIniPts=Block[{x,y},y=Table[i,{i,conHeight/2-0.5h,0.2h,-0.5h}];x=ConstantArray[-conWidth/3,Length[y]];Thread[List[x,y]]];
botWallIniPts=Block[{x,y},x=Table[i,{i,-conWidth/3,-0.4h,h}];y=ConstantArray[0,Length[x]];Thread[List[x,y]]];
incWallIniPts=Block[{x,y},Table[{i,0.2125i},{i,0,(2conWidth)/3,h}]];
rightWallIniPts=Block[{x,y},y=Table[i,{i,Last[incWallIniPts][[2]]+h,conHeight/2,h}];x=ConstantArray[Last[incWallIniPts][[1]],Length[y]];Thread[List[x,y]]];
topWallIniPts=Block[{x,y},x=Table[i,{i,-conWidth/3+0.7h,(2conWidth)/3-0.7h,h}];y=ConstantArray[conHeight/2,Length[x]];Thread[List[x,y]]];
freePos = iniFreePts;
wallPos = leftWallIniPts~Join~botWallIniPts~Join~incWallIniPts~Join~rightWallIniPts~Join~topWallIniPts;
totalPos = freePos~Join~wallPos;
```

where `conWidth=0.4`, `conHeight=0.16` and `h=0.002`

Comment: @xzczd I have edited the `liuQuartic` function so that you can directly copy and paste it into _Mathematica_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Modify the calculation order a little to avoid ragged array and then make use of `Listable` and `Compile`:

```
computeDistance[pos_] := DistanceMatrix[pos, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]
liuQuartic = {r, h} \[Function] 
   15/(7 Pi*h^2) (2/3 - (9 r^2)/(8 h^2) + (19 r^3)/(24 h^3) - (5 r^4)/(32 h^4));
initializeDensity = 
  With[{l = liuQuartic, m = uniMass}, 
   Compile[{{d, _Real, 2}, {h, _Real}}, m Total@Transpose[l[d, h] UnitStep[2 h - d]]]];
new = initializeDensity[computeDistance[N@totalPos], h]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Tested with your new added sample data, my code ran for *0.390000 s* while the original code ran for *4.851600 s* and [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov)'s code ran for *0.813200 s* on my machine.

If you have a C compiler installed, the following code

```
computeDistance[pos_] := DistanceMatrix[pos, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]
liuQuartic = {r, h} \[Function] 
   15/(7 Pi*h^2) (2/3 - (9 r^2)/(8 h^2) + (19 r^3)/(24 h^3) - (5 r^4)/(32 h^4));
initializeDensity = 
  With[{l = liuQuartic, m = uniMass, g = Compile`GetElement}, 
   Compile[{{d, _Real, 2}, {h, _Real}}, 
    Module[{b1, b2}, {b1, b2} = Dimensions@d; 
     m Table[Sum[If[2 h > g[d, i, j], l[g[d, i, j], h], 0.], {j, b2}], {i, b1}]], 
      CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
```

will give you a **2X** speedup once again. Notice the C compiler is necessary, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61509/1871) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I've never thought that `UnitStep` could be used as a Boolean mask to a matrix.

Comment: Wow, that's wired. The original code ran for 2.47 s and ybeltukov's code ran for just 0.2 s on my computer, with data packed in both cases.

Comment: @zjx1805 Then what's the timing for my code?

Comment: It's 0.12 seconds. For now the speedup is pretty satisfactory to me but there is more for me to improve since Matlab can run the complete code at about 0.35 sec/step (even including plotting of data points and exporting of the images) and the amount of computation required for one step for the complete code is at least 3 times larger than the code listed here. I was expecting _Mathematica_ could outperform Matlab.

Comment: @zjx1805 I believe you'll manage to improve the complete code if you fully understand the answers you got. BTW, See my edit for another **2X** speedup.

Comment: Thank you for the latest edit. It seems like an advanced implementation with `Compile` function.

Comment: +1, although the use of compilation method is very cumbersome, but the effect is very good.

Answer (score 20):

You miss that many Mathematica functions are [Listable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html). It allows you to write a fast and clear code

```
init2[distance_] := uniMass Total[liuQuartic[distance, h] UnitStep[2 h - distance], {2}]

h = 0.1;
uniMass = 1.0;
liuQuartic[d_, h_] := d^2 - h^2;
totalPos = RandomReal[1, {1119, 2}];
res1 = initializeDensity@computeDistance[totalPos]; // AbsoluteTiming
res2 = init2@computeDistance[totalPos]; // AbsoluteTiming
res1 == res2
(* {3.088372, Null} *)
(* {0.130059, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

It seems that this code is faster than MATLAB.

Comment: Weirdly the `init2` function takes 9.49 seconds to run on my computer and I don't know why.

Comment: I ran your code, but the new version takes 9.49 seconds to run and it's even slower than the original one.

Comment: @zjx1805 Did you try it with fresh kernel? Which version do you use?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried with fresh kernel. I found that when I replaced your version of `totalPos` with my own version (I listed the way to generate it in the latest edit), the speed significantly reduces, from 0.2 seconds to 4.5 seconds.

Comment: @zjx1805 Probably your data is not [packed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496). Try to apply ``Developer`ToPackedArray@N[...]`` to your data.

Comment: This works, and `N[]` makes the difference. Thank you for your advise and your use of `UnitStep`, and I've never thought that `UnitStep` could be used as a Boolean mask.

Answer (score 8):

Here a slightly improved version of [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871)'s code (I call the function `cinitializeDensity` in the following) that does not require computing the `DistanceMatrix` beforehand. Moreover, I tried to suppress some type casts within the `CompiledFunction` and to exploit parallelization.

```
Block[{r, h},
  cinitializeDensity2 = 
   With[{code = N[liuQuartic[Sqrt[r], h]], m = N[uniMass], g = Compile`GetElement}, 
    Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}, {h, _Real}},
     Block[{r, sum = 0., x1, x2},
      x1 = g[x, 1];
      x2 = g[x, 2];
      Do[
       r = (x1 - g[y, j, 1])^2 + (x2 - g[y, j, 2])^2;
       sum += If[r < 4. h^2, code, 0.],
       {j, 1, Length[y]}];
      m sum
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
     ]]
  ];
```

Along with packing, this leads to further speedup:

```
ptotalPos = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[totalPos]];
a = initializeDensity[computeDistance[ptotalPos]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = cinitializeDensity[computeDistance[ptotalPos], h]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
c = cinitializeDensity2[ptotalPos, ptotalPos, h]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 1.28708
>
> 0.006039
>
> 0.000844
>
> True

For even longer list, it might be worthwhile to delegate the distance checks to `Nearest`:

```
Block[{r, h},
  cinitializeDensity3 = 
   With[{code = N[liuQuartic[Sqrt[r], h]], m = N[uniMass], 
     g = Compile`GetElement}, 
    Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}, {h, _Real}},
     Block[{r, sum = 0., x1, x2},
      x1 = g[x, 1];
      x2 = g[x, 2];
      Do[
       r = (x1 - g[y, j, 1])^2 + (x2 - g[y, j, 2])^2;
       sum += code,
       {j, 1, Length[y]}];
      m sum
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
     ]]
  ];

d = cinitializeDensity3[ptotalPos, Nearest[ptotalPos, ptotalPos, {∞, 2 h}], h]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == d
```

> 0.00126
>
> True