# FDTD Electromagnetic Simulations with Mathematica

Tags: finite-element-method, electromagnetics

Mathematica has some Finite Element capabilities (as explained [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#353016153)). Do you think mathematica is a realistic/sensible option for electromagnetic simulations? (aka making a movie of electric fields propagating through an array of nanoparticles) If so, and anybody has any resources/tutorials I would really appreciate that.

Comment: You mention FEM in the question but FDTD in the title. The question is unclear to me. What exactly are you trying to do, what have you tried? Without a specific problem including code to get started, I doubt you can get a good answer. Of course *Mathematica* can solve time-dependent differential equations, but I can't think of anything beyond this trivial statement that would also fit into the format of a SE post.

Comment: Ok, well I suppose I don't understand these things well enough then. FDTD includes some kind of discretisation of space (and time) into small "elements" in which equations are solved which sounds very similar to FEM to me. Anyway, I want to do some electromagnetic simulations and want to know whether Mathematica is a *good* candidate for this. I'm sure Mathematica *can* do almost anything, but I don't know if it's a sensible choice with which to do FDTD simulations. Specifically I want to model the propagation of EM waves in an anisotropic array of metallic nanoparticles.

Comment: I have tried the software meep but the lack of any debugging drove me insane.

Comment: Practically all the calculations in our paper ["Surface plasmon polariton propagation around bends at a metal-dielectric interface"](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0406153) (link to ArXiV abstract) were done in *Mathematica*. But debugging can be hard in *Mathematica* too - and if you're not familiar with it, that can make it very difficult in practice.

Comment: The question you're asking appears regularly in similar form, just with "electromagnetic" replaced by "some other field." The standard answer is that MMA is best for prototyping, not production code. It's great for combining (symbolic) analytical and numerical work.

Comment: Ok, well I'm already fairly familiar with Mathematica so it could be nice to do my FDTD calculations within it, but may still be too difficult for me, thanks for your comments. I thought this was going to be so much easier when I started out, put a few metallic spheres here, a dielectric there, a plane wave source here and now tell me what happens computer.

Comment: I also used FDTD a couple of years ago in a [paper](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.87.013828). We solved the coupled Maxwell-Schrodinger equation. At the beginning I was doing everything in Mathematica, but moved to Fortran at the end. I agree with Jens that for production maybe you need more than Mathematica.

Comment: FDTD belongs to FDM, you may be interested in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61509/1871). As to the implementation of FDM in _Mathematica_, I should admit though _Mathematica_ can be used for the task, it shows no advantage compared to those lower level language like C, fortran etc. Maybe it's because FDM is so primitive that _Mathematica_ can hardly make its implementation simpler (if it doesn't make it more complex).

Comment: If you want to make use of the FEM capability of _Mathematica_ for electromagnetic simulation, according to my limited experience, I guess (one of) the most troublesome part will be the implementation of the artificial boundary condition which represents an infinite space. There exists some mature technique like convolutional perfectly matched layer (cPML) for FDTD, but no built-in function in _Mathematica_. I believe it's possible to implement something similar in _Mathematica_ with the low level FEM functions, but it requires a good understanding for the artificial boundary techniques.

Comment: @xzczd Trying to implement FDTD in Mma today, it feels like I'm using matlab......