# Efficient discrete Laplacian of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I would like to compute the discrete *Laplacian* of a real matrix (numeric values and full), using any method and targetting efficiency (I will call the *Laplacian* dozens of thousands of time).

I naively defined the following function:

```
laplacian[Z_] := Block[{Zcenter, Ztop, Zleft, Zbottom, Zright},
  Zcenter = Z[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]];
  Ztop = Z[[;; -3, 2 ;; -2]]; 
  Zleft = Z[[2 ;; -2, ;; -3]]; 
  Zbottom = Z[[3 ;;, 2 ;; -2]];
  Zright = Z[[2 ;; -2, 3 ;;]];
  Ztop + Zleft + Zbottom + Zright - 4*Zcenter
]
```

It reduces the dimension of the input (because the *Laplacian* for the elements of the border of the array is not computed) but I am fine with that.

I also tried writing the function in a compiled way:

```
compileLaplacian = Compile[{{Z, _Real, 2}},
  Module[{Zcenter = Z[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]], 
          Ztop = Z[[;; -3, 2 ;; -2]],
          Zleft = Z[[2 ;; -2, ;; -3]], 
          Zbottom = Z[[3 ;;, 2 ;; -2]],
          Zright = Z[[2 ;; -2, 3 ;;]]},
    Ztop + Zleft + Zbottom + Zright - 4*Zcenter
  ]
]
```

but it returns the error

> Compile::cpintlt: 3;;All at position 2 of Z[[3;;All,2;;-2]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.

Can I improve my discrete Laplacian function in terms of computation time? (targeted matrices are $100\times 100$ to $10000\times 10000$)

---

**Edit** The following graph summarizes the timings for the different proposed functions. RAM is not monitored. I'll investigate  Szabolcs's suggestion using packed array to see if timing can be further reduced.

[image]

Full code for the image:

```
laplacian[Z_] := 
  Block[{Zcenter, Ztop, Zleft, Zbottom, Zright}, 
    Zcenter = Z[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]];
    Ztop = Z[[;; -3, 2 ;; -2]];
    Zleft = Z[[2 ;; -2, ;; -3]];
    Zbottom = Z[[3 ;;, 2 ;; -2]];
    Zright = Z[[2 ;; -2, 3 ;;]];
    Ztop + Zleft + Zbottom + Zright - 4*Zcenter]
lapJM[Z_] := 
  Differences[ArrayPad[Z, {{0, 0}, {-1, -1}}], 2] + 
    Differences[ArrayPad[Z, {{-1, -1}, {0, 0}}], {0, 2}]

<< CompiledFunctionTools`
Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"SystemCompileOptions" -> "-fPIC -Ofast -march=native"};

lapxzczd = 
  Hold@Compile[{{z, _Real, 2}}, 
    Module[{d1, d2}, {d1, d2} = Dimensions@z;
      Table[
        z[[i + 1, j]] + z[[i, j + 1]] + z[[i - 1, j]] + 
         z[[i, j - 1]] - 4 z[[i, j]], 
        {i, 2, d1 - 1}, {j, 2, d2 - 1}]
    ], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;

d2 = SparseArray@
   N@Sum[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[i, {#, #} &[Range[1000]], 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2][
      "DifferentiationMatrix"], {i, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}}];

lapJens[values_] := Partition[d2.Flatten[values], Length[values]]

src = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

  DLLEXPORT int laplacian(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, \
MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
      MTensor tensor_A, tensor_B;
      mreal *a, *b;
      mint const *A_dims;
      mint n;
      int err;
      mint dims[2];
      mint i, j;
      tensor_A = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
      a = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_A);
      A_dims = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(tensor_A);
      n = A_dims[0];
      dims[0] = dims[1] = n - 2;
      err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 2, dims, &tensor_B);
      b = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_B);
      for (i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
          for (j = 1; j <= n - 2; j++) {
              b[(n-2)*(i-1)+j-1] = a[n*(i-1)+j] + a[n*i+j-1] + \
a[n*(i+1)+j] + a[n*i+j+1]- 4*a[n*i+j];
          }
      }
      MArgument_setMTensor(Res, tensor_B);
      return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }
  ";
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CreateLibrary[src, "laplacian"];
lapShutao = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "laplacian", {{Real, 2}}, {Real, 2}];

compare[n_] := Block[{mat = RandomReal[10, {n, n}]},
  d2 = SparseArray@
    N@Sum[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[i, {#, #} &[Range[n]], 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 2][
       "DifferentiationMatrix"], {i, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}}];
  {AbsoluteTiming[Array[laplacian[mat] &, 10];], 
    If[n > 1000, {12345, 0}, 
     AbsoluteTiming[Array[lapJM[mat] &, 10];]], 
    AbsoluteTiming[Array[lapxzczd[mat] &, 10];], 
    AbsoluteTiming[Array[lapJens[mat] &, 10];], 
    AbsoluteTiming[Array[lapShutao[mat] &, 10];]}[[All, 1]]]

tab = Table[{Floor[1.3^i], #} & /@ compare[Floor[1.3^i]], {i, 6, 31}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose@tab, 
  PlotLegends -> {"original", "JM", "xzczd", "Jens", "Shutao"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Size", "Time"}]
```

Comment: What is `dx` supposed to be?

Comment: @J.M. Oops, I forgot to mention this. `dx` is the ratio between the "real dimension" (of the continuous problem) and the number of points used in the discretized problem. Using `dx=1` is fine here.

Comment: OK, try `Differences[ArrayPad[Z, {{0, 0}, {-1, -1}}], 2] + Differences[ArrayPad[Z, {{-1, -1}, {0, 0}}], {0, 2}]`.

Comment: @JM see my edit, it works but it seems slower.

Comment: The edit plot might be more informative in log-log axes

Comment: Check out the "MTensor Input Arguments" section in the LibraryLink tutorial. Using ``{Real, 2, "Constant"}`` might further speed things up.

Comment: @masterxilo I suppose your talking about Shutao's function? I am new to _LibraryLink_ and I did not understand from the example how to specify that the `MTensor` are constant. For reference, link to [MTensor Input Arguments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accodrding to your `laplacian[]` function, I can draw the following conclusion:

For a matrix $A_{n\times n}$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots  & a_{1,n} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{1,1} & \cdots  & a_{2,n} \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots  & a_{n,n} \\
\end{array}
\right)_{n \times n}
$$

$$\mathcal{L}(a_{i,j}) \Longleftrightarrow b_{i-1,j-1}=a_{i-1,j}+a_{i+1,j}+a_{i,j-1}+a_{i,j+1}-4 \cdot a_{i,j}$$

where, the $b_{i,j}$ is the element of matrix $B_{(n-2)\times(n-2)}$, and $i=2,\cdots ,n-1, \quad j=2,\cdots,n-1$

Here, I will give a C solution with the help of *LibraryLink* wrapper.

```
src = "
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

DLLEXPORT int laplacian(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    MTensor tensor_A, tensor_B;
    mreal *a, *b;
    mint const *A_dims;
    mint n;
    int err;
    mint dims[2];
    mint i, j, idx;
    tensor_A = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    a = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_A);
    A_dims = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(tensor_A);
    n = A_dims[0];
    dims[0] = dims[1] = n - 2;
    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 2, dims, &tensor_B);
    b = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_B);
    for (i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n - 2; j++) {
            idx = n*i + j;
            b[idx+1-2*i-n] = a[idx-n] + a[idx-1] + a[idx+n] + a[idx+1] - 4*a[idx];
        }
    }
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, tensor_B);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
";
```

---

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CreateLibrary[src, "laplacian"];

lapShutao = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "laplacian", {{Real, 2}}, {Real, 2}]
```

OK, let's test it

```
mat = RandomReal[10, {1000, 1000}];
lapShutao[mat]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

**Remark:**

In my laptop that with 4GB RAM, I discovered that when $n = 15000$, the `lapShutao[]` and `cLa[]` will lead to system halted.

**Update**

For the following code:

```
b[(n-2)*(i-1)+j-1] = a[n*(i-1)+j] + a[n*i+j-1] + a[n*(i+1)+j] + a[n*i+j+1] - 4*a[n*i+j];
```

let `idx = n*i+j`, then the above code could be refactored as below:

```
b[idx+1-2*i-n] = a[idx-n] + a[idx-1] + a[idx+n] + a[idx+1] - 4*a[idx];
```

Comment: What's your timing for `laplacian`? Have you already set something like `"SystemCompileOptio‌​ns"->"-Ofast"`?

Comment: I mean the `laplacian`  written by OP…

Comment: I had to delete the space on the left of `WolframLibrary.h` and in `LIBRARY_NO _ERROR;` in the end. I am preparing a benchmark to compare all proposed functions.

Comment: @anderstood Same in my PC. Thanks for pointing out. (I thought something is wrong again with my compiler before reading your comment! )

Comment: It should be possible to accelerate it by some small multiple using OpenMP parallelization.

Comment: Accepted answer because it's the most efficient according to my experiments; however, other users might also be interested in the simpler solution of `xzcd`.

Answer (score 13):

`ListCorrelate` is a very general function to handle operations of this type. The Laplacian is a correlation with a specific kernel.

```
ker = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, -4, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
ListCorrelate[ker, Z]
```

which gives the same answer as your `laplacian` function. As for speed, this appears to be faster than `laplacian` for small sizes, slower for medium sizes, and faster for larger sizes. Consider the comparison:

```
n = 2^14;
mat = RandomReal[10, {n, n}];
AbsoluteTiming[laplacian[mat]][[1]]
ker = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, -4, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
AbsoluteTiming[ListCorrelate[ker, mat]][[1]]
(*
  81.0357
  35.7189 
*)
```

Comment: It's very short and is fast when the size of the matrix is small (~100) but because very slow when it increases (10 times slower when `Z` is $1000\times 1000$).

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of matrices you have, @anderstood. Are they matrices of exact or inexact numbers? Are they sparse, or packed?

Comment: The Laplacian kernel is separable into two one-dimensional kernels. In principle, less computation would be needed.

Comment: Could you test the performance of my function in your laptop? I cannot do that test because my laptop lacks  enough memory.

Comment: @J.M. Edited. Matrices are full of numeric real values (not sparse nor packed).

Comment: @anderstood If it's only real values, why don't you pack them to improve performance?

Comment: @Szabolcs Aren't matrices packed by default? `mat = RandomReal[10, {1000, 1000}]` then `Developer'PackedArrayQ@mat` returns `True`.

Answer (score 10):

Your compiling fails because `3;;` can't be compiled, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61651/1871) for more information. The easiest fix is to modify it to `3 ;; -1`, but this leads to no improvement for speed. To write a faster laplacian, we can make use of the experience obtained in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61597/1871):

```
cLa = Hold@Compile[{{z, _Real, 2}}, 
     Module[{d1, d2}, {d1, d2} = Dimensions@z; 
      Table[z[[i + 1, j]] + z[[i, j + 1]] + z[[i - 1, j]] + z[[i, j - 1]] - 
        4 z[[i, j]], {i, 2, d1 - 1}, {j, 2, d2 - 1}]], CompilationTarget -> C, 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;

mat = RandomReal[10, {1000, 1000}];
Array[laplacian[mat] &, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.447978, Null} *)
Array[cLa[mat] &, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.084375, Null} *)
```

Comment: That's strange: on my PC (Ubuntu 64 bits), MMA 11.0 gives me the same time for the first one (around 0.4), but between 0.20 and 0.25 for the second one. It's still a substantial gain. I'll check this further a bit later.

Comment: @anderstood I'm on MMA 9.0.1, win10 64bit, with TDM-GCC 4.9.2, `"SystemCompileOptions"->"-Ofast"`

Comment: Thank you, now I have the same timing, using `<< CompiledFunctionTools`Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"SystemCompileOptions" -> 
    "-fPIC -Ofast -march=native"};`

Answer (score 6):

You can get very good speed and additional flexibility by using the built-in functionality described in ["The Numerical Method of Lines"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html). For example, here I assume that the dimensions of the matrix you call `Z` are known *a priori*, so that they can be hard-coded. That allows me to define a matrix `d2` that performs the Laplacian on the flattened version of `Z`:

```
d2 = 
  SparseArray@
   N@Sum[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[i, {#, #} &[Range[1000]], 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]["DifferentiationMatrix"], {i, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}}];

lap2[values_] := Partition[d2.Flatten[values], Length[values]]

Z = RandomReal[10, {1000, 1000}];
Array[lap2[Z] &, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.079342, Null} *)
```

In the function `FiniteDifferenceDerivative`, I could now also specify higher differentiation orders than `2`. The generalization to three dimensions would also be straightforward, by changing the sum to run over `{{2,0,0},{0,2,0},{0,0,2}}` instead of `{{2, 0}, {0, 2}}`.

Another option is to add `,PeriodicInterpolation->True` after the `"DifferenceOrder"` option. So this lets you do lots of variations on the Laplacian very efficiently.