# Why is CompilationTarget -> C slower than directly writing with C?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, librarylink

Probably a hard question, but I think it's better to cry out loud.

I've hesitated for a while about whether I should post this in *StackOverflow* with a `c` tag or not, but finally decide to keep it here.

This question can be viewed as a follow up of [Has this implementation of FDM touched the speed limit of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61509/1871). In the answer under that post, [Daniel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) managed to implement a compiled *Mathematica* function that's *almost* as fast (to be more precise, [3/4 as fast](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61509/has-this-implementation-of-fdm-touched-the-speed-limit-of-mathematica#comment177419_61597)) as the one directly implementing with *C++*, with the help of **devectorization,`CompilationTarget -> "C"`, `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` and `` Compile`GetElement ``**. Since then, this combination has been tested in various samples, and turns out to be quite effective in speeding up `CompiledFunction` that involves a lot of array element accessing. I do benefit a lot from this technique, nevertheless in the mean time, another question never disappear in my mind, that is:

Why is the `CompiledFunction` created with the combination above still slower than the one directly writing with *C++*?

To make the question more clear and answerable, let's use a simpler example. In the answers under [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123855/1871) about Laplacian of a matrix, I create the following function with the technique above:

```
cLa = Hold@Compile[{{z, _Real, 2}}, 
     Module[{d1, d2}, {d1, d2} = Dimensions@z; 
      Table[z[[i + 1, j]] + z[[i, j + 1]] + z[[i - 1, j]] + z[[i, j - 1]] - 
        4 z[[i, j]], {i, 2, d1 - 1}, {j, 2, d2 - 1}]], CompilationTarget -> C, 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;
```

and [Shutao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9627/goodbye-m-se) create one with *LibraryLink* (which is almost equivalent to writing code directly with *C*):

```
src = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  
  DLLEXPORT int laplacian(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, \
MArgument Res) {
      MTensor tensor_A, tensor_B;
      mreal *a, *b;
      mint const *A_dims;
      mint n;
      int err;
      mint dims[2];
      mint i, j, idx;
      tensor_A = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
      a = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_A);
      A_dims = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(tensor_A);
      n = A_dims[0];
      dims[0] = dims[1] = n - 2;
      err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 2, dims, &tensor_B);
      b = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_B);
      for (i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
          for (j = 1; j <= n - 2; j++) {
              idx = n*i + j;
              b[idx+1-2*i-n] = a[idx-n] + a[idx-1] + a[idx+n] + a[idx+1] - 4*a[idx];
          }
      }
      MArgument_setMTensor(Res, tensor_B);
      return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }
  ";
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CreateLibrary[src, "laplacian"];

lapShutao = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "laplacian", {{Real, 2}}, {Real, 2}];
```

and the following is the benchmark by [anderstood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18767/anderstood):

[image]

Why `cLa` is slower than `lapShutao`?

Do we really touch the speed limit of *Mathematica* this time?

Answer(s) addressing the reason for the inferiority of `cLa` or improving the speed of `cLa` are both welcomed.

---

## Update

…OK, the example above turns out to be special, as mentioned in [the comment below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132130/why-compilationtarget-c-is-slower-than-directly-writing-with-c#comment357213_132130), `cLa` will be as fast as `lapShutao` if we extract the `LibraryFunction` inside it:

```
cLaCore = cLa[[-1]];

mat = With[{n = 5000}, RandomReal[1, {n, n}]];

cLaCore@mat; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.269556, Null} *)

lapShutao@mat; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.269062, Null} *)
```

However, the effect of this trick is remarkable only if the output is memory consuming.

Since I've chosen such a big title for my question, I somewhat feel responsible to add a more general example. The following is the fastest 1D FDTD implementation in *Mathematica* so far:

```
fdtd1d = ReleaseHold@
   With[{ie = 200, cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
    Hold@Compile[{{steps, _Integer}}, 
        Module[{ez = Table[0., {ie + 1}], hy = Table[0., {ie}]},
         Do[
          Do[ez[[j]] += hy[[j]] - hy[[j - 1]], {j, 2, ie}];
          ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.];
          Do[hy[[j]] += ez[[j + 1]] - ez[[j]], {j, 1, ie}], {n, steps}]; ez], 
        "CompilationTarget" -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"] /. Part -> cg /. 
     HoldPattern@(h : Set | AddTo)[cg@a__, b_] :> h[Part@a, b]];

fdtdcore = fdtd1d[[-1]];
```

and the following is an implemenation via *LibraryLink* (which is almost equivalent to writing code directly with C):

```
str = "#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  #include <math.h>
  
  DLLEXPORT int fdtd1d(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument \
Res){
    MTensor tensor_ez;
    double *ez;
    int i,t;
    const int ie=200,steps=MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    const mint dimez=ie+1;
    double hy[ie];
  
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 1, &dimez, &tensor_ez);
    ez = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_ez);
    
    for(i=0;i<ie+1;i++){ez[i]=0;}   
    for(i=0;i<ie;i++){hy[i]=0;}
  
    for(t=1;t<=steps;t++){
        for(i=1;i<ie;i++){ez[i]+=(hy[i]-hy[i-1]);}
        ez[0]=sin(t/10.);
        for(i=0;i<ie;i++){hy[i]+=(ez[i+1]-ez[i]);}
    }
    
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, tensor_ez);
    return 0;}
  ";

fdtdlib = CreateLibrary[str, "fdtd"];    
fdtdc = LibraryFunctionLoad[fdtdlib, "fdtd1d", {Integer}, {Real, 1}];

test = fdtdcore[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.551254, Null} *)    
testc = fdtdc[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.261192, Null} *)
```

As one can see, the algorithms in both pieces of code are the same, but `fdtdc` is twice as fast as `fdtdcore`. (Well, the speed difference is larger than two years ago, the reason might be I'm no longer on a 32 bit machine. )

My C compiler is *TDM-GCC 4.9.2*, with `"SystemCompileOptions"->"-Ofast"` set in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Unrelated to your question it might be easier to write ``With[{Part = Compile`GetElement}, Compile[. . .] ]`` instead of using the replacement.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, for this specific example `With` is a better choice, but when things get more complicated, for example, if the code inside `Compile` involves something like `a[[i, j]] = a[[i, j]] + 1`, then `ReplaceAll` seems to be unavoidable. (We need to use a more complicated rule in this case of course, for example ``With[{cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
    Hold@Compile[……] /. Part -> cg /. 
        HoldPattern@(h : Set | AddTo)[cg@a__, b_] :> h[Part@a, b]]``)

Comment: C-`CompiledFunction` expressions carry raw `LibraryFunction` objects as last elements. You can test speed of `cLaLib = Last@cLa` to factor out overhead of `CompiledFunction` and compare only speed difference between handwritten and auto-generated C-code. Part of slowness of `CompiledFunction` is related to fact that [it performs one additional copy of result](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92178/14303) so this overhead grows linearly with size of result.

Comment: @jkuczm I think you should give an answer. Though this technique doesn't speed up the FDTD example much, it makes `cLa` as fast as `lapShutao`!

Answer (score 18):

Using `Compile` with `CompilationTarget->"C"` does generate C-Code to be compiled in a generalized way, the resulting code will contain some overhead due to that compared to hand-written code which can easily explain any difference in runtimes. Even for cases where that overhead is minimal or non-existent automatic code generation will always produce something that is very different from what manually written code would look like, so it is no surprise that the runtimes can differ quite a lot.

I did not find a reference which documents that clearly, but I think when using `cLa=Compile[...,CompilationTarget->"C"]` what is actually compiled is what you get with:

```
ExportString[cLa, "C"]
```

If you look at the result, you clearly find that the generated code is very different from what you would write manually, it more looks like some intermediate state on the way to compile to the WVM: loops are changed into gotos, data access is at a very low level. If you look at the code, it is easy to imagine that the compiler will have a harder time to optimize that code than it has for the nested loop in Shutaos code. The generated code also seems to switch between the one-based Mathematica indices and the zero-based C-indexing at the innermost loop level, using a block local temporary variable. That alone might explain (some of) the runtime differences. The latter is probably easiest to see for something like this:

```
tst = Hold@Compile[{{z, _Real, 2}}, Table[z[[k, 1]], {k, Length[z]}], 
   CompilationTarget -> C, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold
ExportString[tst, "C"]
```

Comment: Thanks for exploring. I should say I'll feel a bit surprising if the code _at very low level_ finally turns out to be the culprit. (I had a vague impression that machine-like code is easier to understand for the compiler.)

Comment: @xzczd understanding which kind of code is easy to optimize for a compiler is certainly out of my knowledge. I know it was hard 20 years ago and I think it hasn't become easier today. All I know is that it was (and still is) possible to see tremendous differences in runtimes if you manage to formulate code in a way which lets the compiler see its opportunities to optimize its output. And that means that lower level code not automatically is easier to optimize than more abstract formulations. That is by the way also true for formulating Mathematica code on a different abstraction level.

Comment: 千金市骨，hope someone will come up with a complete answer someday :)

Comment: @xzczd: I see my answer more to be a "no answer" so I feel a bit stupid to get a bounty for it, especially as the other answers did put more effort in their analysis. As for your hope - while I always am interested to learn new things I'm afraid that a more detailed analysis would be quite some effort, need high skills in understanding compiler functionality and output AND still be specific to this very code (and probably even for the target processor/platform)...

Answer (score 6):

This is only a partial answer, but it was too long for a comment.

It seems that you can slightly increase the speed of the MMA code generated for `cLa`, by dealing in details with the options of `Compile`.
Let us introduce

```
cLabis = Hold@Compile[{{z, _Real, 2}}, 
 Module[{d1, d2}, {d1, d2} = Dimensions@z; 
  Table[z[[i + 1, j]] + z[[i, j + 1]] + z[[i - 1, j]] + z[[i, j - 1]] - 
    4 z[[i, j]], {i, 2, d1 - 1}, {j, 2, d2 - 1}]], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
True}, RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineOverflow" -> False , 
"CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False, 
"CatchMachineIntegerOverflow" -> False, 
"CompareWithTolerance" -> False, "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False, 
"WarningMessages" -> False, 
"RuntimeErrorHandler" -> Function[Throw[$Failed]]}
] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;
```

In particular, we note that we turned off the `EvaluateSymbolically` option, which is not turned off by the choice `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`. I also ensured that all the parameters of `CompilationOptions` were specified.

One can then compare the runtimes of these various functions using (40s to run this)

```
compare[n_] := 
Block[{mat = RandomReal[10, {n, n}]}, 
d2 = SparseArray@
N@Sum[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[i, {#, #} &[Range[n]], 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2][
   "DifferentiationMatrix"], {i, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}}];
{AbsoluteTiming[Array[cLa[mat] &, 10];], 
AbsoluteTiming[Array[lapShutao[mat] &, 10];], 
AbsoluteTiming[Array[cLabis[mat] &, 10];]}[[All, 1]]]

tab = Table[{Floor[1.3^i], #} & /@ compare[Floor[1.3^i]], {i, 6, 
 31}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose@tab, 
PlotLegends -> {"cLa", "Shutao", "cLabis"}, 
AxesLabel -> {"Size", "Time"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

In the end, you get a comparison of the form
[image: Time comparisons]

Unfortunately, the gain only remains very minor...

Comment: I think the `d2` inside `compare` is redundant?

Comment: @xzczd I naively copy-pasted the code for `compare` from the associated [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123855/efficient-discrete-laplacian-of-a-matrix)...