# Compile Flatten with list as second argument

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

If you try to evaluate code in which `Flatten` uses a List as second argument, like the following:

```
foo = Compile[{{u, _Real, 2}},
  Flatten[u, {1, 2}]
  ]
```

Mathematica will complain with the following error message:

```
Compile::cpint: {1,2} at position 2 of Flatten[u,{1,2}] should be a machine-sized integer; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

Using an integer as second argument of `Flatten` indeed gives no error.

Why is this? And is there a way around it?

My particular use case is to use `Flatten` to convert a `TensorProduct` structure into a structure similar to that given by `KroneckerProduct`,
that is, to do something like in the following (but for any number of matrices in the `TensorProduct` structure):

```
fooMatrix = TensorProduct[
    Array[a, {2, 2}], Array[b, {2, 2}], Array[c, {2, 2}]
  ];
Flatten[fooMatrix, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}]
```

It also [seems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/27539) that `ArrayFlatten`, which could probably be tweaked to work here instead of `Flatten`, is not compilable (as also shown by trying to compile it and observe the `CompilePrint`).

Comment: Where is the form `Flatten[u, {1, 2}]` documented? I cannot find it.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer interestingly, I just noticed it isn't, not directly at least. It seems to work the same as `Flatten[u, {{1, 2}}]`. Using the latter form gives the same problem with `Compile` though (and is indeed the one I'm interested in using, I used the one with a rank-1 list as second argument here just to make a simple reproducible example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I'd like to point out that, even if a function is [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871), its functionality is usually limited inside `Compile`. It's not rare to find a valid syntax of a compilable function isn't compilable. I think in this case the description after `Compile::cpint` is clear: the 2nd argument of `Flatten` can only be an integer inside `Compile` i.e. the 4th syntax in the document of `Flatten` is just not supported inside `Compile`, period.

Then how to circumvent this? The only solution I can think out is to self-implement it with `Table`, with the technique mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132130/1871) to make it as fast as the built-in:

```
iter[j_] := {i[j], dim[j]}

lst = {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6};

cf = With[{g = Compile`GetElement}, 
     Hold@Compile[{{u, _Real, 6}}, 
           Module[{dim = Dimensions@u}, 
            Partition[Flatten@Table[##], dim[2] dim[4] dim[6]]], CompilationTarget -> C, 
           RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] &[
        g[u, ## & @@ i /@ Range@6], ## & @@ iter /@ lst] /. 
       i[j_] :> RuleCondition@ToExpression["i" <> ToString@j] /. dim[j_] :> g[dim, j]] //
     ReleaseHold // Last;

test = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}];

rst1 = Flatten[test, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.015607, Null} *)

rst2 = cf@test; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.015645, Null} *)

rst2 == rst1
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that trying to [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) is going to buy you any speed up. For instance, let's suppose we were interested in using just [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) with 1 argument. Using the following data:

```
data=RandomReal[1,{10,10,10,10,10,10}];
```

Let's compare a compiled versus non-compiled version:

```
fc = Compile[{{x, _Real, 6}}, Flatten[x]];
r1 = fc[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Flatten[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r1 === r2
```

> {0.006045, Null}
>
> {0.002228, Null}
>
> True

So, the non-compiled version is faster. Even if a 2-arg version of [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) were compilable, I think the non-compiled version would probably be faster.

Comment: While I see your point, if you want to compile a more complex function that uses Flatten as part of the computation, this prevents the whole function from being compiled efficiently. This actually arose while trying to compile the partialTrace function of my other question