# Fast multiplication of high dimensional matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I am very new to **Mathematica**. I am dealing with the multiplication of matrix as the following code

```
c=8;d=64;
a=RandomReal[{1,2},{c,c,c}];
b=RandomReal[{1,2},{c,c,c,d,d,d}];

s=0.0;
Do[s=s+a[[i1,i2,i3]]*b[[i1,i2,i3,;;,;;,;;]],{i1,1,c},{i2,1,c},{i3,1,c}] //AbsoluteTiming

{4.26894, Null}
```

For me, the computation time is too high because there are many such multiplication in the program.

Any suggestions really appreciated.

Comment: Better try `s = Total[a b, 3]` or `s = Flatten[a].ArrayReshape[b, {c^3, d, d, d}];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code can be faster if we compile:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Real, 3}, {b, _Real, 6}}, Flatten[a].Flatten[b, 2]];

test = cf[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.492055, Null} *)
```

and even faster if compile to C and extract the `LibraryFunction[…]`:

```
cfc = 
  Compile[{{a, _Real, 3}, {b, _Real, 6}}, Flatten[a].Flatten[b, 2], 
    CompilationTarget -> C][[-1]];

testc = cfc[a, b]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.234145, Null} *)
```

Tested on *v9.0.1*, with TDM-GCC-5.1.0-2 64-bit compiler, `"SystemCompileOptions"->"-Ofast"`.

Comment: Huh? Why does extracting the `LibraryFunction` speed this up?

Comment: @Henrik Copying large list is slow. I learned this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132130/why-is-compilationtarget-c-slower-than-directly-writing-with-c#comment357213_132130).

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, very useful answer.

Answer (score 6):

Better try

```
s = Total[a b, 3];
```

or

```
s = Flatten[a].ArrayReshape[b, {c^3, d, d, d}];
```

On my machine, the latter is faster. In general, rephrasing summations in terms of `Dot` (`.`) should lead to more efficient code as `Dot` is highly optimized.

Comment: In _v9.0.1_ `Flatten[a].Flatten[b, 2]` seems to be faster and more memory-efficient.

Comment: Good point. Both lead to the same `AbsoluteTiming` and `MaxMemoryUsed` on my machine under version 12.0 for macos. I recall that `ArrayReshape` used to have some performance degradation when it was introduced. They seem to have been resolved.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.