# How can we improve performance when passing data to a function?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I have a defined function $F(x,y,z)$ and data of $(x,y)$ and would like to evaluate the sum of F over data and at different z values. Here is a minimal example:

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x  y  z];
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, 0.05}, {y, -2, 2, 0.05}], 1];
ParallelTable[
   Sum[F[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, Length@data}], {z, 0, 10,
     0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{11.4345, Null}
```

I tried to compile to speed it up but did not get that much enhancement

```
Fc = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, Sin[x  y  z], 
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM"];
ParallelTable[
   Sum[Fc[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, Length@data}], {z, 0, 
    10, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{9.85097, Null}
```

Is there still a way to increase the speed?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're doing really high-level evaluation that cannot be `Compile`d, forget about parallelization. For more info see

[Why won't Parallelize speed up my code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/1871)

Then, based on the experience obtained from

[Has this implementation of FDM touched the speed limit of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61509/1871)

It's not hard to achieve the following:

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x   y   z];
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, 0.05}, {y, -2, 2, 0.05}], 1];

ref = ParallelTable[
    Sum[F[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, Length@data}], {z, 0, 10, 
     0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {12.0628, Null} *)

cf = 
   Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}}, 
        Table[Sum[F[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, Length@data}], {z, 0, 10, 
          0.01}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
      DownValues@F /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.655155, Null} *)

tst = cf@data; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0694954, Null} *)

tst - ref // Abs // Max
(* 1.49214*10^-13 *)
```

Compiled with Clang compiler in Win10, corresponding setting is

```
$CCompiler = {"Compiler"->GenericCCompiler, 
"CompilerInstallation"->"C:\\progra~1\\LLVM",
"CompilerName"->"clang.exe",
"SystemCompileOptions"->"-Ofast"}
```