# Compile does not boost the speed

Tags: performance-tuning, data, compile

I have these functions that are used to define`MyFun` below

```
F[x_, y_] = {{0, (17 I)/10, 
   2  Cos[1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], (0.2` + 
      0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], 
   2  Cos[1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)], (-0.2` + 
      0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)]}, {-((
    17 I)/10), 
   0, (-0.2` + 0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], 
   2  Cos[1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], (0.2` + 
      0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)], 
   2  Cos[1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)]}, {2  Cos[
     1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], (-0.2` - 0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[
     1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], 0, -1.4722431864335457` - 0.85`  I, 
   2  Cos[x], -((2 Cos[x])/
    5)}, {(0.2` - 0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[
     1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], 
   2  Cos[1/2  (x - Sqrt[3]  y)], -1.4722431864335457` + 0.85`  I, 
   0, (2 Cos[x])/5, 
   2  Cos[x]}, {2  Cos[
     1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)], (0.2` - 0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[
     1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)], 2  Cos[x], (2 Cos[x])/5, 0, 
   1.4722431864335457` - 
    0.85`  I}, {(-0.2` - 0.34641016151377546`  I)  Cos[
     1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)], 
   2  Cos[1/2  (x + Sqrt[3]  y)], -((2 Cos[x])/5), 2  Cos[x], 
   1.4722431864335457` + 0.85`  I, 0}}
f1[x_, y_] = D[F[x1, y1], x1] /. { x1 -> x, y1 -> y};
f2[x_, y_] = D[F[x1, y1], y1] /. { x1 -> x, y1 -> y};
tft[r_, er_] = If[r <= er, 1, 0];
```

and this is `MyFun`

```
MyFun[x_, y_, z_] := Block[{val, fun, order, reslt},
  
  {val, fun} = Eigensystem[F[x, y]];
  order = Ordering[val]; 
  val = val[[order]];
  fun = fun[[order]];
  
  reslt = (Sum[
     If[in == jn, 
      0, (tft[val[[jn]], z] - 
         tft[val[[in]], 
          z])  ((( 
           Conjugate[fun[[jn]]] . f1[x, y] . 
            fun[[in]] )*(Conjugate[fun[[in]]] . f2[x, y] . 
            fun[[jn]])))], {in, 6}, {jn, 6}]); Im@reslt
  ]
```

with this data

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, 0.5}, {y, -2, 2, 0.5}], 1];
```

I evaluate

```
Table[ParallelSum[
    1/Length@data   MyFun[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, 
     Length@data}], {z, -1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{4.16042, Null}
```

with `Parall` on `Table`, it is faster

```
ParallelTable[
   Sum[1/Length@data   MyFun[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, 
     Length@data}], {z, -1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{2.66483, Null}
```

and finally with `Compile`  but almost the same speed

```
compilMyFun = 
 Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, MyFun[x, y, z], 
  CompilationTarget -> "WVM", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

which gives

```
ParallelTable[
   Sum[compilMyFun[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, 
     Length@data}], {z, -1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{2.71059, Null}
```

I was wondering if speed can be boosted more because my real data length is about 40000.

Comment: `MyFun` contains `Eigensystem` and `Ordering` which are already compiled. That's why you should not expect any improvement here.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, is there another way to boost speed?

Comment: Maybe you can find a formulation of the result for `MyFun` that does not require the eigendecomposition?

Comment: If that's not possible, I would probably try to call `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` of the _Eigen_ package via `LibraryLink`. The point about using _Eigen_ is that it might have a more performant implementation for small matrices of fixed size. It is a _C++_ library, so this requires some _C++_ experimence and some fiddling.

Comment: Alternatively, one can of course also try to call the _LAPACK_ routine `zheev` directly. (One should assume that this is what _Mathematica_ does, but I am not sure.)

Comment: Just as a reminder: 
Compile`CompilerFunctions[]  gives a list of functions for which Compile has maybe some benefit.

Comment: Have you read https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871 ?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher OP's function involves heavy low-level calculation, so `Compile` still helps quite a bit. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's a bit sad to see that OP seems to have learned nothing from [my answer to his previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/299978/1871). Please remember `Compile` is advanced tool and it's not something that'll have effect if you just use it blindly. Please consider starting from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871) if you really want to learn its usage, and please don't miss those links in my previous answer.

Anyway, let me do a favor. The keypoint is to take the uncompilable `Eigensystem` out. Function and variable definitions that are same as yours are omitted in this answer.

```
ref = ParallelTable[
       Sum[1/Length@data MyFun[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, 
           Length@data}], {z, -1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.96491, Null} *)

help = 
  func |-> Unevaluated@
     Compile[{x, y}, func[x, y], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@func;

{cf1, cf2, cF, ctft} = help /@ {f1, f2, F, tft};

MyFun[x_, y_, z_, val_, fun_] := 
   Im@Sum[If[in == jn, 
    0., (tft[val[[jn]], z] - 
       tft[val[[in]], z])*(Conjugate[fun[[jn]]] . f1[x, y] . fun[[in]]*
              Conjugate[fun[[in]]] . f2[x, y] . fun[[jn]])], {in, 6}, {jn, 6}]

cMyFun = 
  Hold@Compile[{x, y, z, {val, _Real, 1}, {fun, _Complex, 2}}, 
        MyFun[x, y, z, val, fun], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
        CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@MyFun /. {f1 -> cf1, f2 -> cf2, 
      tft -> ctft} /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;

eigen[x_, y_] := Module[{val, fun, order},
   {val, fun} = Eigensystem[cF[x, y]];
    order = Ordering[val]; 
    {val[[order]], fun[[order]]}]

eigenlst = eigen @@@ data // Transpose; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0050079, Null} *)

cf = 
  Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {val, _Real, 2}, {fun, _Complex, 3}}, 
       Table[Sum[MyFun[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z, val[[i]], fun[[i]]]/
          Length[data], {i, Length[data]}], {z, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
       CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. MyFun -> cMyFun /. 
    Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;

tst = cf[data, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0585079, Null} *)

ref - tst // Abs // Max
(* 2.77556*10^-17 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for being a slow learner:-)

Comment: what is the definition of `eigen`? in `eigen @@@ data // Transpose`

Comment: @MMA13 Oh I forgot to post it. Added.

Answer (score 2):

Just launching the parallel Kernels can take a few seconds.
Putting
Once @ LaunchKernels[];
on top and just adding an `N@`  operation in your `F[x_,y_]` definition
like `F[x_, y_] = N@{` ...
does speed things up a bit and on a 16-core Windows computer using Mathematica 14.0 I get a speed of half a minute for a data list of 6561 elements, so I think your problem is just solvable within minutes.
If you really need more speed: Use Fortran !