# Sum of a set of elements in a array?

Tags: summation, list-manipulation

For a function I do this (`Integrate` over circular range):

```
NIntegrate[x*y Boole[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 3], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]
```

Now, I want to do the `Sum` of the circular set of elements in a square array.

---

Thanks for your 1st answers and sorry to not have been clear enough.

Example: from a two-dimensional `{n, m}` array `mat`, I would like to sum all the elements included in a circle of radius `r` and located at `{x0, y0}`.

Something like this:

```
Sum[mat[[n]][[m]] Boole[Sqrt[(n-x0)^2 + (m-y0)^2] < r], {n, x0-r, x0+r}, {m, y0-r, y0+r}]
```

Would you do it differently?

And next step, I would like to increase `r` up to the `Sum = mySum`.

I hope I'm clearer.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34827/1871 .You just need to `Total@Flatten@#&` after you extracting the desired elements.

Comment: What is `mySum`? Is it some value you choose before-hand, and you want to find `r` such that the sum is equal (or at least close) to `mySum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant. Do comment if this is not what you meant.

I would use Sum within Sum. Something like the following:

```
In[24]:= Sum[
  Sum[x*y Boole[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 3], {x, 1, 5, 0.1}], {y, 1, 5, 
   0.1}]/100

Out[24]= 6.4424
```

With smaller step size...

```
In[25]:= Sum[
  Sum[x*y Boole[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 3], {x, 1, 5, 0.01}], {y, 1, 5, 
   0.01}]/10000

Out[25]= 6.1591
```

As you decrease the step size, you should see the result approaching that found by NIntegrate, namely 6.125

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but in case you meant that:

You have a square $n$ by $n$ matrix `mat`, and that you want to compute the sum of elements which are within a circle inscribed in the matrix, then you can do:

```
Total[ DiskMatrix[(n-1)/2] * mat, 2]
```

This assumes that `n` is odd so the circle can be properly centred.

References: [`DiskMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiskMatrix.html), [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)