# Map vs. Table for index-specific operations on 2D arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, map, coding-style, index

Many experienced users on this site tend to use Map (and its variants, MapAt, MapIndexed, etc.) rather than Table.  When applying the same operation to every element of an array, Map does seem more semantically direct. For instance:

```
test2D = {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}};
Table[g[test2D[[row, col]]] + 1, {row, 1, Length@test2D}, {col, 1, Length@test2D[[row]]}];
MatrixForm[%, TableAlignments -> Left]
Map[g[#] + 1 &, test2D, {2}];
MatrixForm[%, TableAlignments -> Left]
```

But when I need to carry out index-specific (i.e., position-specific) operations on higher-dimensional(>=2D) arrays, I find Map and its variants more challenging than Table.

For instance, suppose I want to raise each element in a 1D array to a power equal to its position.  That I can do with either Table or MapIndexed:

```
test1D = {a1, a2, a3};
Table[test1D[[col]]^col, {col, 1, Length@test1D}]
Flatten[MapIndexed[#1^#2 &, test1D], 1]
```

But suppose I want to raise each element in a 2D array to a power equal to its row no. x column no.  With Table that's conceptually straightforward:

```
Table[test2D[[row, col]]^(row*col), {row, 1, Length@test2D}, {col, 1, Length@test2D[[row]]}]
```

But how would one do that with MapIndexed? It would be nice if it were just something like:

```
MapIndexed[#1^(#2*#3) &, test2D]
```

where #2 were the column index and #3 were the row index, but it doesn't work like that.

Finally, suppose you have more detailed index-specific operations in a 2D array. That seems to be where Table really shines, but I'd be interested to hear of alternatives.  E.g., suppose that, from each successive 4-element block of data in a row, you need to extract the 2nd and 4th elements, but only when all four elements are present.  Thus, in a row of {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}, you need {{a2, a4}, {a6, a8}}.  And you need to do this for each successive row.  Further, the rows have variable lengths. With Table, this does the job:

```
test2Dx = {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, 
a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20}, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, 
b8, b9, b10, b11}, {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7}, {d1, d2, d3, d4, 
d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, d16, d17}};

Table[{test2Dx[[row, 2 + col*4]], test2Dx[[row, 4 + col*4]]}, {row, 1, Length@test2Dx}, {col, 0, (Floor[N[Length[test2Dx[[row]]]/4]]) - 1}];

MatrixForm[%, TableAlignments -> Left]
```

Is there a semantically straightforward way to do this using other functions (e.g., Map or its variants and a pure function)—or is this a use case for which Table makes more sense?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many index-specific operations can be implemented via `MapIndexed` with a level specificaton. Your `Power` example can be written as:

```
MapIndexed[#1^(#2[[1]]*#2[[2]]) &, test2D, {2}]
```

If you want better readability of indices you can define an auxiliary function:

```
myPower[x_, {n1_, n2_}] := x^(n1 n2);
MapIndexed[myPower, test2D, {2}]
```

Some index-specific operations can be implemented without indices at all. The last example in your question can be coded in a functional form as:

```
Map[Downsample[#, 2, 2] &, Map[Partition[#, 4] &, test2Dx], {2}]
```

This expression can be also rewritten in a more verbose way:

```
splitInBlocksOf4 = Partition[#, 4] &;
takeEvenElements = Downsample[#, 2, 2] &;
Map[takeEvenElements, Map[splitInBlocksOf4, test2Dx], {2}]
```

In many cases, the functional approach is shorter, faster and less error-prone than index-based solutions.

Comment: Just a side note: if speed is concerned, the definition `myPower[x_, {n1_, n2_}] …` should be avoided because function definition based on pattern matching can't be auto-compiled. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/705/1871

Comment: @Shadowray.  This is a *very* nice answer since, in addition to providing working syntax that addresses each of my questions, you also offer verbose versions of each to help with reader understanding.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Shadowray. Also, I see that, because my target indices were {2nd, 4th}, these could be easily captured with a simple Downsampling by 2's within each 4-element block. But suppose I had a different array (call it test2Dy) with blocks of, say, length 11, and wanted to pull out the 3rd and 7th members of each. In that case, would `Downsample` still work easily, or might `Part` be preferred, as follows?: `Map[{#[[3]], #[[7]]} &, Map[Partition[#, 11] &, test2Dy], {2}]` or, equivalently, `{#[[3]], #[[7]]} & /@ Partition[#, 11] & /@ test2Dy`.

Comment: @theorist I would prefer an expression which closer reflects my intentions.
If I want to specifically extract elements number 3 and 7 (e.g. because 3 describes apples and 7 describes oranges), then I will use explicit indices `{#[[3]], #[[7]]} &`. If I, for example, want to reduce the number of elements by factor of four and avoid the elements which are too close to the ends of a list, then I will use something like `Take[#, {3, -3, 4}]&`. This way it will be easier to read and maintain in the future.

Comment: I like the concept of 'reflecting intent' — it provides a nice criterion for good code design.   I did some timing checks on the code for test2Dx.  Setting `test2Dx = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {1000, 1000}]`, RepeatedTiming gave the following results:  `Table[{test2Dx[[row, 2 + col*4]], test2Dx[[row, 4 + col*4]]}, {row, 1, Length@test2Dx}, {col, 0, (Floor[N[Length[test2Dx[[row]]]/4]]) - 1}]` : **0.4 s**; `Map[Downsample[#, 2, 2] &, Map[Partition[#, 4] &, test2Dx], {2}]` : **20.2 s**; `{#[[2]], #[[4]]} & /@ Partition[#, 4] & /@ test2Dx` : **0.03 s**. Any idea why the Downsample code is so much slower?

Comment: @theorist `Downsample` is a high-level function which internally uses `Part`. In addition it performs a lot of checks. (See ```GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Downsample]```). While `Part` is a built-in kernel function. That's why using `Part` directly is much faster.

Comment: FYI, in case you'd like to take a crack at Part II:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203664/map-vs-table-for-index-specific-operations-on-2d-arrays-part-ii

Answer (score 10):

We don't need to avoid `Table` in my view. In cases that `Table` is more straightforward, just use `Table`. If speed is concerned, `Compile` it. Here is an example:

[Can I generate a "piecewise" list from a list in a fast and elegant way?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34827/1871)

Nevertheless, your 2 examples (especially 2nd one) don't belong to the cases that `Table` is more straightforward, at least for someone familiar enough with list manipulation of *Mathematica*, I'm afraid. Do remember list manipulation is more than "`Map` and its variants".

The following is my solution:

```
# /@ #@test2D &[#^Range@Length@# &]   

Partition[#, 2] &@#[[2 ;; ;; 2]] & /@ test2Dx
```

BTW if `test2D` is not ragged i.e. `ArrayQ` returns `True` for `test2D`, I'll:

```
{dim1, dim2} = Range@Dimensions@test2D    
((test2D^dim1)\[Transpose]^dim2)\[Transpose]
(* Alternatively: *)
test2D^Outer[Times, dim1, dim2]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97035/discussion-on-answer-by-xzczd-map-vs-table-for-index-specific-operations-on-2d).