# Map vs. Table for index-specific operations on 2D arrays–Part II

Tags: functional-style, list-manipulation, map

This is an extension of my recent question, [Map vs. Table for index-specific operations on 2D arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203203/map-vs-table-for-index-specific-operations-on-2d-arrays)

For that question I gave a minimal working example, since I was more interested in learning generally about a functional approach to index-specific operations on 2D arrays than in solving my specific problem.

The answers I received were very helpful in enabling me to see how a functional approach could be more syntactically straightforward than my usual tool for such problems (`Table`).   But when I tried to apply that functional approach to my actual problem (which I have solved with `Table`), I ran into trouble.

Here is some sample data.  Each row starts with an employer number, and is followed by 11 fields of data for each employee of that employer.  This contains data for two employers, nos. 125 and 126; no. 125 has two employees, and no. 126 has three.

```
t = {{125.`, "Employee Number(See line above)", " 1", 
    " Date of Birth", " 11/24/1969", " Sex", " Male", 
    " Employee's Home 5 digit Zip Code", " 22202", 
    " Current Insurance", " Employee Only", " Permanent", 
    "Employee Number(See line above)", " 2", " Date of Birth", 
    " 06/12/1972", " Sex", " Female", 
    " Employee's Home 5 digit Zip Code", " 22204", 
    " Current Insurance", " Employee and Children or Family", 
    " Permanent"}, {126.`, "Employee Number(See line above)", " 1", 
    " Date of Birth", " 12/04/1967", " Sex", " Female", 
    " Employee's Home 5 digit Zip Code", " 90024", 
    " Current Insurance", " Employee and Spouse or Domestic Partner", 
    " Temporary", "Employee Number(See line above)", " 2", 
    " Date of Birth", " 11/04/1971", " Sex", " Male", 
    " Employee's Home 5 digit Zip Code", " 90021", 
    " Current Insurance", " Employee Only", " Permanent", 
    "Employee Number(See line above)", " 3", " Date of Birth", 
    " 02/13/1967", " Sex", " Male", 
    " Employee's Home 5 digit Zip Code", " 90021", 
    " Current Insurance", " Employee Only", " Temporary"}};
```

Suppose I want to pull out the local employee no. (1, 2, 3, etc.), DOB, gender, zip code, type of insurance, and employment status for each employee.   I can do that with `Table` (DataViaTable1) but, as I learned from my last question, a functional approach is more semantically straightforward (DataViaMap1) [N.B.: Both of these give the same output, so I've only pasted one screenshot.]

```
DataViaTable1 = Table[Table[ { t[[ROW, 3 + COL*11]], t[[ROW, 5 + COL*11]], 
 t[[ROW, 7 + COL*11]], t[[ROW, 9 + COL*11]], 
 t[[ROW, 11 + COL*11]], t[[ROW, 12 + COL*11]]} , {COL, 
 0, (Floor[N[Length[t[[ROW]]]/11]]) - 1}], {ROW, 1, Length@t}];
DataViaTable1 // TableForm

DataViaMap1 = {#[[2]], #[[4]], #[[6]], #[[8]], #[[10]], #[[11]]} & /@ 
 Partition[#, 11] & /@ Rest /@ t;
DataViaMap1 // TableForm
```

[image]

But what I actually need is to create a unique ID for each employee, which is the (employer ID x 100) + (local employee ID).  For instance, the 2nd employee of employer 125 would have an employee ID of 12502.  I then need to prepend that to the data for each employee. With `Table`, that's easy to do (`Rationalize` coverts the employer number to an exact number, and `ToExpression` is needed because the local employee no. is a string):

```
DataViaTable2 = 
  Table[Table[ { 
     Rationalize[t[[ROW, 1]], 0]*100 + 
      ToExpression@t[[ROW, 3 + COL*11]], t[[ROW, 5 + COL*11]], 
     t[[ROW, 7 + COL*11]], t[[ROW, 9 + COL*11]], 
     t[[ROW, 11 + COL*11]]} , {COL, 
     0, (Floor[N[Length[t[[ROW]]]/11]]) - 1}], {ROW, 1, Length@t}];
DataViaTable2 // TableForm
```

[image]

Is there a simple (simpler than my `Table` syntax) way to do this using a functional approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Flatten[{parent = 100 Rationalize[#[[1]], 0]; 
      {parent + ToExpression[#[[2]]], #[[4]], #[[6]], #[[8]], #[[10]]} & /@ 
      Partition[Rest[#], 11]} & /@ t, 1];
% // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you convert your table into a `Dataset`:

```
parseRecord[employerNum_][data_] := <|Join[{"Employer" -> employerNum}, Rule @@@ Partition[data, 2], {"Status" -> Last[data]}]|>;
parseEmployer[{employerNum_, rest___}] := BlockMap[parseRecord[employerNum], {rest}, 11];
dataset = Dataset@Flatten@Map[parseEmployer, t];
```

then creating new fields will be more straightforward:

```
dataset[All, Join[<|"New ID" -> Round[100 * #["Employer"]
                             + ToExpression@#["Employee Number(See line above)"]]|>, #] &]
```

Comment: You are missing the status `"Permanent"` or `Temporary"`

Comment: @rhermans thank you. I have added it.

Comment: I selected MelaGo's as the accepted answer, as it was closer to what I was looking for.  Having said that, I very much appreciate your answer, as it introduces me to MMA's `Dataset` functionality, an area I've been meaning to explore.  Thank you.