# How to make the code inside Compile conciser without hurting performance?

Tags: compile

Consider the following sample:

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

fdtd1d = Compile[{{steps}}, 
   Module[{ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[ez[[2 ;; -2]] += hy[[2 ;; -1]] - hy[[1 ;; -2]];
       ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10];
       hy[[1 ;; -1]] += ez[[2 ;; -1]] - ez[[1 ;; -2]], {n, steps}];
       ez]];

fdtd1d[1000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0100000, Null}
> ```

Apparently there're 2 sentences (of course in real situation there can be more) with same structure that can be represented with a function if `fdtd1d` is built with `Function`:

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[list1_, list2_, end_] := 
  list1[[end ;; -end]] += (list2[[2 ;; -1]] - list2[[1 ;; -2]]);

fdtd1d = Function[{steps}, 
   Module[{ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[f[ez, hy, 2]; ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.]; f[hy, ez, 1], {n, steps}];
    ez]];

fdtd1d[1000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.1050000, Null}
> ```

But this method isn't available for `Compile`, even with the trick mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/compiling-more-functions-that-dont-call-mainevaluate/24597#24597):

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

ClearAll[f];
f = Function[{list1, list2, end}, 
   list1[[end ;; -end]] += (list2[[2 ;; -1]] - list2[[1 ;; -2]]), 
   HoldFirst];

fdtd1d = Compile[{steps}, 
   Module[{ez = ez, hy = hy}, 
    Do[f[ez, hy, 2]; ez[[1]] = Sin[n/10.]; f[hy, ez, 1], {n, steps}];
    ez], CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@fdtd1d
```

> Compile::argset: The assignment to Compile`FunctionVariable$1571 is illegal; it is not valid to assign a value to an argument. >>
>
> ```
> ……
> 1 Return Error
> ```

So, as the title said, is there a way to make the code inside `Compile` conciser without performance decreasing or even compilation failure?

Comment: Another approach you may prefer: write the code programmatically, then compile it. This way it doesn't matter how verbose it is.

Comment: @OleksandrR. You mean what Leonid Shifrin has done below? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your code:

```
ie = 200;
ez = ConstantArray[0., {ie + 1}];
hy = ConstantArray[0., {ie}];

ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[list1_, list2_, end_] := 
    list1[[end ;; -end]] += (list2[[2 ;; -1]] - list2[[1 ;; -2]]);
```

With the help of the `withGlobalFunctions` macro, defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns/746#746), you get simply:

```
fn=
    withGlobalFunctions[
        Compile[                
            {steps},
            Module[{ez=ez,hy=hy},
                Do[f[ez,hy,2];ez[[1]]=Sin[n /10.];f[hy,ez,1],{n,steps}];ez
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

which is exactly how you'd like this. The result is the same as if you'd expand the definitions by hand. And of course, the speed is the same too:

```
fn[1000]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.009366, Null} *)
```