# Problem with pdetoode for two coupled PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation, finite-difference-method

I tried to adapt a code for a single equation to solve the following system using ['pdetoode'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/87074)

**Updated answer**

```
domain = {0, 1};
difforder = 4;
points = 25; 
grid = Array[# &, points, domain]

With[{p = p[t, x], q = q[t, x]},
sy = {D[q, t] - D[q, x, x] + p == 0, D[p, t] + D[p, x, x] + q == 0};
ic = {q == Sin[Pi x] /. t -> 0, q == 0 /. t -> 0.4};
bc = {{p == 0, q==0} /. x -> 0, 
{p==0, q==0} /. x -> 1};]
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{p, q}[t, x], t, grid, difforder];
removeredundant1 = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
removeredundant2 = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
ode@1 = removeredundant1@ptoofunc@sy[[1]];
ode@2 = removeredundant2@ptoofunc@sy[[2]];
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = ptoofunc@With[{sf = 1}, diffbc[t, sf]@bc];
var = Outer[#[#2] &, {p, q}, grid];
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode /@ {1, 2}, odeic, odebc}, var, {t, 0, 0.4}];
```

I got the error

> There are more dependent variables..., than equations, so the system is underdetermined

Any hint is appreciated.

**Edit**
as mentioned by @xzczd, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/62616) is close to my case. I adapted it accordingly but still got the 2nd error "There are more dependent variables .. than equations, so the system is underdetermined."

It worked quite easily without 'pdetoode' as:

```
System = {D[q[x, t], t] - D[q[x, t], x, x] + p[x, t] == 0, 
D[p[x, t], t] + D[p[x, t], x, x] + q[x, t] == 0, 
p[x, t] == 0 /. x -> 0, p[x, t] == 0 /. x -> 1, 
q[x, t] == 0 /. x -> 0, q[x, t] == 0 /. x -> 1, 
q[x, 0] == Sin[Pi x], q[x, 0.4] == 0};

{q, p} = NDSolveValue[System, {q, p}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.4}]
```

> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}, 0., 0.4}}, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}, 0., 0.4}} }..

```
Plot3D[q[x, t], {t, 0, 0.4}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: …You're using `pdetoode` blindly. Please re-read [my answer to your question 4 years ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192981/1871), then read the document of `Part` (`[[]]`), `Span` (`;;`) and `Map` (`/@`) and think about how to _make room_ for your i.c.s/b.c.s. Also, you're setting `q == 0 /. t -> 0.4` as a constraint, this looks like an [ill-posed problem](http://old.math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf), are you sure it is well-posed? If not, then please notice `pdetoode` is just auxiliary tool for implementation of FDM, and naive FDM won't be able to handle ill-posed problem.

Comment: @xzczd thanks for your reply. Okay, I'll re-try. The problem is well-posed, it worked without 'pdetoode' but I'd like to compare..

Comment: @S.Maths I am curious, could you share how you have done this without pdetoode?

Comment: @user21 see my edit.

Comment: @xzczd see my updated answer.

Comment: @S.Maths Looking at your solution without pdetoode  plot of `q[x,t]` shows numerical problems near `x==0`. Your statement "It worked quite easily" does not hold  I think

Comment: @UlrichNeumann which problems do you mean? I added the plot.

Comment: @S.Maths Sorry I meant `Plot3D[p[x, t], {t, 0, 0.4}, {x, 0, 1}]
`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann you're right. I was interested in $q[x,t]$.

Comment: @S.Maths Ok, but one point should be mentioned. If you eliminate `p[x,t]` you get one pde for `q[x,t]` $-q^{(0,1)}(x,t)+q^{(4,0)}(x,t)+q(x,t)=0$ , but this new pde isn't fullfilled by your solution `q[x,t]` !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149463/discussion-between-s-maths-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: Still, you're coding blindly. You need to know more about list manipulation of Mathematica, and finite difference method. See the figure in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28011/1871 and think carefully about which function you should use (`pdetoode` or `pdetoae`?) and where you should remove the equations.

Comment: @S.Maths Your solution "without pdetoode" isn't trustable. `q` looks fine , `p` looks critical. How can you conclude that one solution part is correct?